# Where does Ubuntu store the picture that I set as my desktop?

Tags: customization, desktop-background

I have a pretty picture set as my desktop background, but I've lost the original file. However, my desktop is still set to this picture. How can I get back my picture?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Open up the file browser and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, to show hidden files (ones that start with a `.`), now navigate to `.cache` → `wallpaper`.

Or hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `nautilus .cache/wallpaper/`

[image]

Comment: These seem to be zoomed versions of the original. Does Ubuntu also store the original file somewhere?

Comment: No, it doesn't - unfortunately. You can use `find / 2> /dev/null | grep warty` to search everywhere on your disk. Replace warty with something that you would expect in the file name of the image. *Perhaps* there happens to be a copy somewhere, but nautilus doesn't create one.

Answer (score 4):

If your image came from the internet, then I would suggest taking a Screenshot (Applications->Accessories->Take Screenshot).

Then upload your screenshot to [TinEye.com](http://www.tineye.com/). On the results page select "Biggest Image" from the left hand side navigation. Then look to see if the website has found your image.

This "Reverse Image Search" has enabled me to do what you're doing before.

Comment: This is another good trick.

Answer (score 3):

If you run `gconftool --get /desktop/gnome/background/picture_filename` in a terminal then it will output the location of the image file.

(GConf is the GNOME settings manager, and `/desktop/gnome/background/picture_filename` is the particular setting you are retrieving. You can also browse these settings graphically by using the [gconf editor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17249/how-do-i-use-the-gconf-editor).)

Or hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type

```
 eog `gconftool --get /desktop/gnome/background/picture_filename`
```

(this opens your image with the default image viewer, Eye of GNOME)

Answer (score 0):

In the case when you absolutely misplace a file and aren't able to get  online to ask about the location of where it might be stored, always remember this... it has helped me a lot throughout the years.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to get shell, then:

`locate` (type file name you are looking for here, without the parentheses)

**NOTE:** if you've never used `locate` before you'll need to run `updatedb` first like this:

```
sudo updatedb
```

or if you are already `root`, just run `updatedb`, usually it can take time so I run it in the background like this:

```
sudo updatedb &
```

the `&` causes the command to be run in the background, you can type `jobs` to see if its still running, but you'll get notified when it terminates like this:

```
[1]+ Done     updatedb
```

Some people hate the shell, but even so, I have found it good to learn both GUI and shell no matter what OS you are using. There ARE going to be times when something can't be done via the GUI, esp in a linux environment. This was very true when it came to bridging ethernet interfaces, etc..