# What is dconf, what is its function, and how do I use it?

Tags: dconf, gsettings

Mark Shuttleworth [recently blogged](http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/568) about the decision to include the Qt libraries in the 11.10 release, with a [followup from](http://www.jonobacon.org/2011/01/18/some-further-notes-on-qt-in-ubuntu/) Jono Bacon. Mark states that the biggest challenge to integrating apps written in Qt into the larger Ubuntu system is Qt's current non-compatibility with dconf.

What is dconf, and what is the role it plays in Ubuntu?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use the gconf editor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17249/how-do-i-use-the-gconf-editor)

Answer (score 112, accepted):

### Introduction

As other answers on this site discuss `gconf` and `dconf` together, I will just concentrate on discussing command-line tools such as `gsettings` and the gui `dconf-editor` that are used to access the `dconf` database.

At [the GNOME official site](https://live.gnome.org/dconf) it is noted that

> dconf is a low-level configuration system. Its main purpose is to provide a backend to GSettings on platforms that don't already have configuration storage systems.
>
> dconf is a simple key-based configuration system. Keys exist in an unstructured database (but it is intended that keys that logically belong together are grouped together).
>
> Having all of the keys in a single compact binary format also avoids the intense fragmentation problems currently experienced by the tree-of-directories-of-xml-files approach.
>
> dconf is optimised for reads. Typically, reading a key from dconf involves zero system calls and zero context switches.
>    Writes are less optimised -- they traverse the bus and are handled by a "writer" -- a DBus service -- in the ordinary way.

### Using `gsettings` to view and change settings

Once one gets to know `gsettings` it can be as easy as the gui `dconf-editor`. The options can be listed by entering `man gsettings` or going to the [Ubuntu manpages online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/gsettings.1.html).

**NOTE:** As everyone's system has different programs installed, you may have to substitute the specific items I choose for different ones when experimenting yourself, as I am using XUbuntu XFce with quite a lot of GNOME programs.

To list all the available schemas, enter

```
gsettings list-schemas
```

To also include all the keys, enter

```
gsettings list-recursively
```

**However**, it is usually easier to specify what you want with, for examples,

```
gsettings list-schemas | grep -i shotwell
```

This returns a long list; I have shortened it to:

```
org.yorba.shotwell
org.yorba.shotwell.preferences.ui
org.yorba.shotwell.preferences.slideshow
org.yorba.shotwell.plugins.enable-state
org.yorba.shotwell.printing
org.yorba.shotwell.preferences.editing
org.yorba.shotwell.preferences.files
```

Now when you have found the schema that you are interested in, list the keys with

```
gsettings list-keys org.yorba.shotwell.preferences.ui
```

This returns a list (again I have shortened it):

```
background-color
display-basic-properties
display-extended-properties
display-photo-ratings
display-photo-tags
display-photo-titles
event-photos-sort-ascending
event-photos-sort-by
```

Pick one and see what the current value is with

```
gsettings get org.yorba.shotwell.preferences.ui display-photo-tags
```

This returns a value of true, so to reverse it, use

```
gsettings set org.yorba.shotwell.preferences.ui display-photo-tags false
```

These are *trivial* examples, but show basically how keys and values are identified and changed with `gsettings`.

### Using dconf-editor to change settings

The GUI program, `dconf-editor` is installed with [dconf-tools](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/dconf-tools) package by clicking [here](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/dconf-tools) or by running

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Then run it by entering in the terminal or in the quick launch menu, `dconf-editor`.

As you can see in the screenshot, all the various schemas can be expanded on the left hand side and the appropriate key selected. It is very straightforward to navigate to the value you want (in this case the `gnome-mplayer` preferences). You can click the check box to have a value activated or add a numerical value into one of the other boxes. You can also search within dconf editor with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> keyboard shortcut.

[image]

You can also add another log say to `log-viewer` by adding a path in the form ['/var/log/auth.log', var....'] in the screenshot below.

[image]

### Conclusion

There are many other useful ways that you can tweak settings with both `gsettings` and `dconf-editor` and they are straightforward to use. It is worth looking through them to see if there are options there that are not in the programs' preferences, as you may be able to customize your program just the way you want. As fossfreedom recently showed in this question

- [How do I edit the list of music library locations in Rhythmbox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/189265/how-do-i-edit-the-list-of-music-library-locations-in-rhythmbox/189686#189686)

knowing how to use `gsettings` or `dconf-editor` is extremely valuable. See also:

- [How do I use the gconf editor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17249/how-do-i-use-the-gconf-editor)

Comment: Since the programs `gsettings` and `dconf-editor` work both on the `dconf` database, why don't they show the same information? `gsetting` on 12.04 shows values for the schema `com.canonical.Unity.Launcher` and the key `favorites` but `dconf-editor` does not even offer `com.canonical.Unity` let alone the full schema or the key.

Comment: @A.H: good question. I've asked it here: http://askubuntu.com/q/243409/2355

Comment: @A.H. I'm sorry that I forgot to answer your comment: I can't comment on Unity because I'm on Xubuntu, but Flimm has asked a separate question which should get some good answers.

Comment: But what on earth makes dconf incompatible with Qt, a GUI toolkit?

Comment: On RHEL / CentOS use `yum install dconf-editor` to install the GUI tool.

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04.2, install dconf by `sudo apt-get install dconf-editor`

Comment: I don't know why this answer is accepted; it's more or less just a user guide advertising a GUI interface as ease of use. What is dconf? Is it a just a GUI app as this explanation focuses on? Isn't it a service? It runs on startup then? How do apps interact with it? Can dconf based apps run without the service? How does it work? All the GUI usage advice could be dropped and a shorter text could surely provide many more answers. I still don't really know what dconf is or how it works. I just know how to use the GUI settings. But I knew that already.

Answer (score 35):

For those coming from windows that want a simple reply, dconf is the gnome equivalent to the windows registry... a big binary tree where any program can store and share their configuration.

They first migrated from the traditional unix configs (one text files for each app, each with their own format) to a standard tree of XML files, managed by gconf. In recent times, as almost no one edited those XML files directly and the performance problems of reading and parsing MANY files, they migrated to a binary format by migrating from gconf to dconf.

Unlike windows registry, dconf should have all config entries listed, even if they are set to the default values. So there are no hidden entries, you can change then or reset then to default easily.

Comment: It's not only gnome equivalent, but all DE (Desktop Environment) equivalent. Most packages that are built for DE (Desktop Environment packages, like KDE, Xfce, Cinnamon packages and so on) have some configuration stored there.

Comment: @R.W.Prado Not true, not all DE use dconf. While there are several Gnome forks and GTK based DE (GTK is the one that requires dconf ),  there are lot more DE out there that do not use GTK and the main ones, usually QT based, like KDE,  DO NOT use dconf: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dconf (search for kde). check https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/desktop_environment and see each DE package requirements, most, if not all, non-gtk DE do not use dconf

Comment: Interesting! You completed my comment. My mistake was worth it  =)

Answer (score 13):

dconf is not Ubuntu specific, it's the GNOME technology used to store application settings.
For more details please read
http://live.gnome.org/dconf

Comment: What is the relationship between dconf and gconf?

Comment: dconf is the GNOME3 replacement for gconf which has not been maintained for some time. dconf is also expected to bring performance improvements over gconf (relevant for applications startup).

Comment: The question in [psusi](http://askubuntu.com/users/8500/psusi)'s comment above is partially answered in the answers to the question "[Why the controversy about dconf and gconf?](http://askubuntu.com/q/34490/3256)". I'm sure [psusi](http://askubuntu.com/users/8500/psusi) is aware of it, having commented on the question, but in case anyone else wants to know more, there it is.