# Can I use dconf-editor to modify Gconf settings?

Tags: gconf, dconf

Can I get "dconf-editor" to show as much information as "gconf-editor" did in 11.04?

I find using the gconf version much easier and has better application integration.

I have both installed. Are there additional packages to make this improvement?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No. There is a transition going on here since `gconf-editor` (xml backend) is going to be phased out in favor of `dconf-editor` (gnome 3 binary blob). So, you can expect more and more settings in gconf to become invalid or removed and new settings to appear in dconf.

More info:

- [When to use gconf vs dconf?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91403/when-to-use-gconf-vs-dconf)
- [What is dconf, what is its function, and how do I use it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22313/what-is-dconf-and-what-is-its-function)
- [What are the differences between gconf and dconf?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34490/what-are-the-differences-between-gconf-and-dconf)

Comment: xml has been around a long time now trading for a binary blob.

Comment: xml is very slow. Binary blob is very fast :+