# Permanent custom keyboard shortcuts for Evince (Document Viewer)

Tags: 10.10, gnome, shortcut-keys, gconf, evince

I am using the Ubuntu document viever [Evince](http://projects.gnome.org/evince/). Lately, I found out how to add custom keyboard shortcuts for the program. I was searching for a way to add a shortcut e.g. for *View / Best fit* (also available as a button). What I found was the [Keyboard shortcut page](http://library.gnome.org/users/evince/stable/shortcuts.html.en) which describes how to setup shortcuts using *gconf-editor*. That worked as described. However, once I restart my system the shortcuts are gone. How can I set them permanently?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**For Ubuntu 12.04 and up:**

Use `dconf-editor` instead of `gconf-editor`:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Then set the key `/org/gnome/desktop/interface/can-change-accels` to **true**.

**Setting shortcuts when using global menu:**

1. Open evince (or any app) with `UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 evince`
2. Browse menus, hover an entry, type your shortcut

Comment: The tutorial does not use *dconf* but *gconf*. They also state that I can "Uncheck the value box for can_change_accels in the right side of the window." after I am done.

Comment: Im guessing you're using 11.10 or up ? That tutorial is probably outdated. See [gconf vs dconf](http://askubuntu.com/questions/122039/dconf-editor-and-gconf-editor) for explanations. You can still uncheck the box when you're done editing.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I am still running Ubuntu 10.10. (Maverick).

Comment: Im sorry I didnt ask before :p You might want to edit your question with an ubuntu 10.10 tag and add "menu shortcuts" or "accels" in the title.

Comment: Starting evince with `UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 evince` from the command line to set the shortcuts helped. One should add this to the tutorial I started with. Thank you, user55822!

Comment: [this does not work for toolbar entries](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/1526432), so one cannot create shortcuts for history navigation (back/forward)

Comment: @sds so neither can we modify `next page` = `Ctrl+PgDown` ? :(

Comment: Neither `dconf` nor `gconf` are working for me on Trusty Tahr (14.04). Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: [Does not work in Ubuntu 16.10](http://askubuntu.com/q/866982/156688).

Answer (score 2):

This question is identical to another one, where I suggested a way to edit the config file to alter the keys: https://askubuntu.com/a/899956/495717