# Is there any simple way to edit shortcuts for any app?

Tags: shortcut-keys

Is there any simple way to edit shortcuts for any app ? (I am using ubuntu 12.04, and I didn't find anything really clear by googling or searching on askubuntu)

Comment: In fact, I am looking from some generic method in order to change default desktop shortcuts, to change the chromium ones. Because I am used to mac, and on it you can create and change as many shortcut you want

Comment: If you mean keybindings for entries in menus (eg Nautilus -> ctrl+N) then read that http://askubuntu.com/questions/136062/permanent-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-for-evince-document-viewer/

Comment: A little off-topic, but in KDE there is a "Standard Keyboard Shortcut" module that lets you change the default keyboard shortcuts used in all KDE apps. Not to mention that every KDE app individually lets you customize its shortcuts usings its own Settings menu -> Configure Shortcuts.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Open `System Settings`, then `Keyboard`, and then the Shortcuts tab.

Is this what you're looking for?