# Ubuntu 16.04 : impossible to create a new document on GUI with right click

Tags: 16.04, nautilus, gui, document

I have a small bug since several months, when I do a right click on the file explorer I cannot create a new document, it's a blank area.

Here a screen-shot attached.

[image: try to create new document]

Comment: Your screenshot shows *New Document* not *New Folder* (first entry) it should work there. What happens on Shift+Ctrl+N?

Comment: Yes you are right thanks. I have correct it, I cannot create a new document, not a folder.

Comment: This Q&A may help you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/208291/how-to-create-a-new-blank-file-in-nautilus-3-6-and-above