# forward slash to search in evince removed with upgrade to 14.04

Tags: gnome, search, evince

It used to be the case (pre 14.04) that one could search a PDF with the forward slash, then cycle through the results with F3. Seemingly now that has been removed - I can only manage to search with ctrl-F and then cycle through results with by clicking the mouse.

Is this intentional? Any way to revert it? I assume this is part of the ongoing process to remove all useful functionality from Gnome?

Comment: I am not on 14.04 but you might be able to cycle through the results with CTRL+G and CTRL+SHIFT+G. These are shortcuts commonly used in GNOME apps.

Comment: On the face of it it works, but in evince it gets stuck in a repeating loop on one page. The GNOME decisions to remove functionality really piss me off - the notion that interfaces are ever going to be consistent is completely at odds with the fact that now every web designer adds inconsistencies on every web page (and to this question, are using / to search, not ctrl-shift-alt-F3-F7-Super-G).

Comment: Absolutely agree with you on that.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer proposes a solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136062/permanent-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-for-evince-document-viewer), by setting the dconf property `dconf>org>gnome>desktop>interface>can-change-accels` to true, hovering over the menu item, and typing a new shortcut.

But [it doesn't work for everyone](https://askubuntu.com/questions/555401/how-to-customize-add-keyboard-shortcuts-for-evince), myself included.