# Ctrl + < not working with Guake

Tags: shortcut-keys, guake

I was using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd><</kbd> as a shortcut to show Guake in 11.10. Now when I define the shortcut it recognizes the combination but when I try to use it it doesn't work. Instead, it recognizes <kbd><</kbd> as being the shortcut.

This is happening in more than one computer.

Any ideas why?

Comment: This seems not to be a problem of Unity/Ubuntu but of Guake - as you can set Ctrl+< as shortcut for other applications - which work. But I can repeat and confirm what you described for Guake.

Comment: doesn't work for Gnome 3 as well

Answer (score 4):

There is a workaround described here:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Guake#.27Ctrl.27_Keybind_Problem

Answer (score 1):

I have put this on their track as an issue:
http://guake.org/ticket/454

In the meantime, I'd say you'll have to use some other shortcuts.

@edited by Postadelmaga:
In the ticket page there is also a patch: I have downloaded 0.4.4 code and applied the patch and it work fine now

Comment: That link is not working. 404

Comment: yeah, 3 year passed. And Ubuntu 11.10 is not there anymore, is it?

Answer (score 1):

That happens because of a bug in new versions of Guake and there's a workaround for that in gnome that is described in the wiki, and it worked perfectly for me in Ubuntu 16.04:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>' keybind problem:

As of Guake 0.4.2-7 there has been a noted bug affecting multiple users concerning the use of the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key to toggle Guake window visibility (i.e. users that setup <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> to open the Guake console are able to open it by just pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>, independent on whether <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key has been pressed).

To solve the problem, you should manually fix the value of the [DConf](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34490/what-are-the-differences-between-gconf-and-dconf#34497) key `/apps/guake/keybindings/global/show_hide`. Open a gconf-editor, navigate to apps > guake > keybindings > global > show_hide and replace `<Primary>` with `<Control>`.

If you don't have `gconf-editor` installed (it's not installed by default in the newest versions of Ubuntu) you just need to install it by searching for it in the "Ubuntu Software Center" or in terminal using this command:

```
sudo apt install gconf-editor
```

Source: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Guake#.27Ctrl.27_Keybind_Problem

**Edit**: I know there's already an answer with the same link, but I've added a way to install gconf-editor and this way if the link dies, the workaround stays.

Answer (score 1):

Or if you are lazy like and don't want to install gconf-editor, just add a keybinding in keyboard shortcuts for the command: `guake -t` or `guake`.