# Guake shortcut keys: odd behaviour

Tags: guake

I have the problem described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142034/ctrl-not-working-with-guake): i.e. shortcut keys (Shift Ctrl up) suddenly not working.

The solution is, apparently: "you should manually fix the value of the DConf key `/apps/guake/keybindings/global/show_hide`"

but i cannot find this in gconf-editor as they suggest. (I installed guake using ppa:linuxuprising/guake). Thus i cannot fix it manually

**Update:** I changed the shortcut key to something arbitrary, i.e. from <kbd>Ctrl shift up</kbd> to <kbd>alt pgup</kbd> and then the old shortcut key started working, i.e. <kbd>Ctrl+shift+up</kbd> now works (even though the preferences in GUI indicate <kbd>alt pgup</kbd>). I did the same for <kbd>Ctrl+shift+down</kbd> (changed to <kbd>alt left-arrow</kbd>) and now it works again. I then changed it back and repeated to confirm the behaviors.

Comment: I don't know which action that shortcut it suppose to trigger. That's a dconf database path: `dconf read /apps/guake/keybindings/global/show-hide`. Use `write` to set any other value ('F12' by default). Maybe you mean to [this issue](https://github.com/Guake/guake/issues/994), _Toggling Guake visibility does not work (Wayland)_. You could create a shortcut to `guake-toggle` or `guake -t`.

Comment: thanks a lot. I didn't know about dconf, i just installed gconf-editor but /apps/guake/keybindings does not appear, I can't navigate to it. I will try using 'write' instead as you suggest. My issue isn't the "toggle guake visibility" issue, f12 is working fine, but within the terminal the usual "ctrl+shift+up arrow" does not scroll up as it normally does

Comment: @PabloBianchi i ran "dconf write /apps/guake/keybindings/global/show-hide" and it says:
(dconf:24745): GLib-CRITICAL **: 22:02:43.985: g_variant_parse: assertion 'text != NULL' failed
i should mention: i installed guake using ppa:linuxuprising/guake

Comment: Read carefully the command you're running. You are writing nothing/null to that path. I don't know anything about that PPA, please uninstall and remove everything and install the official way. [These ones](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/475149/209677) doesn't work?

Comment: it is the official way: https://guake.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/installing.html#system-wide-installation Re nothing/null to path: I thought i just ran what you indicated. In any case, the path doesnt exist, i knew it was futile