# Changes made in gconf-editor have no effect

Tags: gnome

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with Gnome 3.4.2. Changes I make in "gconf-editor" have no effect in Gnome, but they do when I load Gnome classic. For example, changing the order and position of caption buttons had no effect (they remained where they were), but when I logged out and entered Gnome classic, it changed. Also, suddenly, when I try to adjust font hinting (from "slight" to "full") in "advanced settings", nothing happens. I tried making changes both as a normal user and as root, both without luck.

Comment: Please have a look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/22313/what-is-dconf-and-what-is-its-function and http://askubuntu.com/questions/91403/when-to-use-gconf-vs-dconf and http://askubuntu.com/questions/34490/what-are-the-differences-between-gconf-and-dconf

Comment: Thank you Rinzwind, dconf-editor did it. Caption buttons were easily changed by going to org>gnome>shell>overrides>button-layout.

Comment: made it an answer @user8526

Answer (score 2):

`g-conf` is being phased out. `dconf-editor` is the new `gconf-editor`.

Of course you can `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools` or click this button:

[image: Install via the software center]