# How do I move window buttons from left to right using command line or by editing a specific file?

Tags: command-line, gnome

I know that Ubuntu has a file hidden somewhere deep inside it that holds the old metacity values for changing the position of the menu buttons. My question is how can I do this **WITHOUT** Ubuntu Tweak in Ubuntu Classic?

"Why not use the thing that's already done?"

- That thing was written by finding this file once then making a mental note of it to create a GUI to solve the problem, which is all fine and dandy.
- I want to learn where this stuff is for myself because I like knowing how to do things from the command line. (Also, come on, how many times have you seen a dude in a coffee shop using the command line interface to mess with stuff?)
- It could be helpful to note the directory for others because of installing other themes to gnome-classic (*cough* new macbuntu port *cough*)

**I would also like to know if this is a text file that I may be able to change with vim, emacs, gedit, etc.**

Comment: Canonical refuses to implement any option for this in 16.04, see [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1622043): "The window controls in Unity are on the left. It is not a setting, it's where the designers chose to place them. **This will not change.**". I personally find this incredibly obtuse, but, you get what you pay for.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can move buttons to the right with:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout ':close,minimize,maximize'
```

or, maybe better to twitch "close" button with "maximize" button:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout ':maximize,minimize, close'
```

And move them back to the left with:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout 'close,minimize,maximize:'
```

To get the current settings, use:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout
```

See [`man gsettings`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/gsettings.1.html) for more info, and, as a bonus:

[image: dconf Editor]

In this case the changes are made in `~/.config/dconf/user` file which is expected to be in the [binary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_file) dconf (GVDB) database format.  Only programs like `dconf Editor` or `gsettings` can  ***safely*** edit this file.

More about:

- [dconf System Administrator Guide](https://wiki.gnome.org/dconf/SystemAdministrators)
- [Do dconf use EXI binary XML?](https://askubuntu.com/q/201888/147044)
- [What is dconf, what is its function, and how do I use it?](https://askubuntu.com/q/22313/147044)
- [What are the differences between gconf and dconf?](https://askubuntu.com/q/34490/147044)

Comment: @RaduRadeanu I guess I need to edit the question to read, where is the file?

Comment: @ColeBusby There isn't a file you can edit IIRC, dconf is binary.

Comment: @Oli Okay, Just making sure, so gsettings is the ONLY way to make these changes yes? Also where are themes stored? (images and the like)

Comment: @ColeBusby See my new edits.

Comment: `... minimize, close'` <-  with this space didn't work for me. I removed it before execute.

Comment: It is also possible to have both, at least with some windows: `'close,minimize,maximize,menu:menu,maximize,minimize,close'`.

Answer (score 1):

I found this question searching for a way to move buttons from left to right using for the whole system. I am using autologin-guess. So everyting the system get restarted this setting got lost.

Create a file `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/60_our-own.gschema.override`
with this content:

```
[org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences]
button-layout=':minimize,maximize,close'
```

Then execute this command:

```
glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
```

Reboot your system.