# What is the preferred way to store application settings?

Tags: development, application-development

From a developer's perspective. Should I use a text-based config in /etc or in $HOME? Or something else?

Comment: I lack the expertise to know whether they would be _preferred_ or not, but [GConf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GConf) and [dconf](http://askubuntu.com/q/22313/3256) are other ways to store application settings.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Personally, I prefer plain files because I have nightmares about the registry of windows. In my opinion the ideal way of storing settings is plain text files, preferably with a standard format (INI, JSON, XML, YAML etc.). A single database (especially dconf which is monolithic) is a single point of failure.

Comment: ás: Thanks for sharing: I learned some new things from your comment that will come in handy if I ever get around to writing some software of my own!

Comment: I'm glad it helps you :)

Comment: Related : http://askubuntu.com/questions/59822/where-to-store-user-settings-for-an-app

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are talking about a system wide daemon, a file in `/etc` is appropriate.  If you are talking about an application that should have per-user settings, the home directory is appropriate.  For new apps, it would be a good idea to follow the XDG Base Directory specification:

http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html

This basically states that you should store your config files in `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME`, which defaults to `~/.config`

Comment: Why no mention of dconf/gsettings?