# Where to store user settings for an app?

Tags: python, settings, application-development

If I want my application to store a few settings, that persist when an application closes, then where should I store them?

I'm not talking anything complicated: two booleans and a string (although in the future I might want to store more complex settings)

I've heard gconf, dconf, gsettings, etc all mentioned. What is the "preferred" method? Preferably one that's nice and easy in Python.

Comment: Related :http://askubuntu.com/questions/42438/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-store-application-settings

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`gconf` is deprecated, so for a new project I would not use it. `dconf` is a backend for storing the settings, as an application developer you should normally not have to bother with it.

What you seem to need is `gsettings`, a high-level API ([API documentation for C](http://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GSettings.html)) to store/retrieve settings without bothering how/where they are actually stored. `gsettings` is part of `gio`, which is one of the core packages of gnome (like `glib` and `gobject`). This [blog post](http://zderadicka.eu/gsettings-flexible-configuration-system/) gives a short introduction how to use it with Python.

If you do not want any dependencies on `gio` (e.g. you are not developing a GNOME application) and want to store simple config files, I'd suggest to use the `$HOME/.config` directory (or whatever directory defined by `$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS`) instead of `$HOME/.your_appname`, in line with the [freedesktop spec](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/latest/).

Comment: It seems your link to the blog post is dead. Any chance you have another?

Comment: @Seth unfortunately the blog post I was linking to does not seem to be available anymore. I replaced the link with a link to another blog post that should also be a good starting point.

Answer (score 10):

#### Application runs system wide

the appropriate place to store settings would be:

```
/etc/[application]/
```

where a subdirectory is optional.

---

#### Application runs in a **per user** mode

settings should be stored in the user HOME, preferably in a hidden directory:

```
/home/<user>/<.application>/
```

See also the [Debian FHS](http://wiki.debian.org/FilesystemHierarchyStandard).

---

#### Applications running in [X-Desktop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedesktop.org)

Applications for the X-Desktop (e.g. GNOME, KDE, Unity, Xfce) should refer to the [XDG Base Directory Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) where the following file locations are defined in local variables:

> - **`$XDG_DATA_HOME`** defines the base directory relative to which user specific data files should be stored. If $XDG_DATA_HOME is either not set or empty, a default equal to $HOME/.local/share should be used.
> - **`$XDG_CONFIG_HOME`** defines the base directory relative to which user specific configuration files should be stored. If $XDG_CONFIG_HOME is either not set or empty, a default equal to $HOME/.config should be used.
> - **`$XDG_DATA_DIRS`** defines the preference-ordered set of base directories to search for data files in addition to the $XDG_DATA_HOME base directory. The directories in $XDG_DATA_DIRS should be seperated with a colon ':'.
> - **`If $XDG_DATA_DIRS`** is either not set or empty, a value equal to /usr/local/share/:/usr/share/ should be used.
> - **`$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS`** defines the preference-ordered set of base directories to search for configuration files in addition to the $XDG_CONFIG_HOME base directory. The directories in $XDG_CONFIG_DIRS should be seperated with a colon ':'. If $XDG_CONFIG_DIRS is either not set or empty, a value equal to /etc/xdg should be used.

Comment: No, they should be in /home/<user>/.config/application/

Comment: @Anonymous: It would be cool to have a reference for this. Present [Debian policy](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-opersys.html) requires FHS 2.3 with the **exception** that applications are **recommended** to store user settings in a dot file (or directory) in user's HOME.

Answer (score 1):

[Quickly](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/), which is is one of the newer helpers for [application development for Ubuntu](http://developer.ubuntu.com/), defaults to storing all preferences with [desktopcouch](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/desktopcouch/Documentation/). 
The advantage is that those settings can be synchronized with other installations via the Ubuntu One tools.