# keyboard shortcut gnome-terminal (ctrl-tab) and (ctrl-shift-tab) in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, shortcut-keys, keyboard, gnome-terminal

Keyboard shortcuts in `gnome-terminal` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>) in 12.04 don't seem to be working. Is there a setting that I dont know of?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

A way to configure this is by setting `gsettings` from the terminal itself (two commands):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/keybindings/ next-tab '<Primary>Tab'
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/keybindings/ prev-tab '<Primary><Shift>Tab'
```

Source: [the last comment in the bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/162000)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Simple, effective, trivial to implement. This answer needs more upvotes.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks. The option no longer appears in dconf editor (in 18.04) as I answered above, but this works.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Works in Ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 20.04, too!

Comment: Confirmed on Ubuntu 16.04. Excellent.

Comment: Somehow this didn't work but dconf did

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 22.04. 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 25):

Use [dconf Editor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22313/what-is-dconf-what-is-its-function-and-how-do-i-use-it). If it's not installed by default you can get it with `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`. The shortcut can be modified at Org > Gnome > Terminal > Legacy > Keybindings.

[image: Screenshot of dconf Editor]

This works for me in Ubuntu Gnome 16.04. Reference: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=738325

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: You can do this without installing anything using `dconf write /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/keybindings/next-tab "'<Primary>Tab'"` and `dconf write /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/keybindings/prev-tab "'<Primary><Shift>Tab'"`

Comment: Just verified for Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 works without any issues.

Comment: This actually worked when gsettings didn't

Answer (score 18):

Unfortunately assigning shortcuts with <kbd>TAB</kbd> key is a no go in Gnome (for whatever reason). So this will not work.

- Reference: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=123994 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/162000
- Current discussion about the issue: https://mail.gnome.org/archives/desktop-devel-list/2009-November/msg00220.html

There is a way to do this in a hacky way, [from the answer below](https://askubuntu.com/a/875482/47254) type this in the terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/keybindings/ next-tab '<Primary>Tab'
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/keybindings/ prev-tab '<Primary><Shift>Tab'
```

Comment: it is really uncomfortable to not have ctrl-tab. Thanks for that though, ive already learned to live without it. I should use ctrl-~ and ctrl-shift-~ now.

Comment: I tend to learn the native shortcuts and use those. So for `gnome-terminal` it's `ctrl-shift-right` & `ctrl-shift-left`

Comment: Another follow up https://mail.gnome.org/archives/desktop-devel-list/2009-November/msg00220.html

Comment: That bug report says it's RESOLVED FIXED, yet the problem seems to exist. Was it just reported fixed without doing anything?

Comment: I have my caps-lock mapped to escape through the OS and then I use Ctrl+Esc for next tab, so on the keyboard I am actually pressing Ctrl+Caps Lock for next tab.

Comment: Really a shame that we have to use workarounds as described below, instead of just allowing to set this via the UI...

Comment: The suggestions below work just fine and have more votes than this one. I feel like one of them should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageUP</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageDown</kbd> (annoying, but it is what we have).

Comment: I tried setting <Primary>Tab for mate terminal with dconf. org/mate/terminal/keybindings/next-tab. It works to change the setting with dconf but mate terminal thinks the shortcut is invalid for some reason. But <Primary>Tab seems to work with gnome terminal.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a little heretic to do in gnome but you can install Konsole and have those shortcuts like so:

```
sudo apt install konsole
```

The shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is set by default.

Note: Konsole is the KDE default terminal

Answer (score 0):

Resetting the dconf to 'factory setting' might help sometime(At least in my case when my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> was not working system wide)

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing very interesting I found days ago is that the gnome does:
 - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> Switch between different application
 - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>(The one above <kbd>Tab</kbd>) Switch between different windows of one application
Try this.