# How can I alter the next/previous tab shortcut in Terminal?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys

I want to change the Next Tab shortcut in Terminal to be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. I tried using the *gconf-editor* as suggested [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/assign-custom-shortcut-keys-on-ubuntu-linux/) but nothing happens when I run that using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. My googling for other solutions has failed. Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select *Edit* in the top menu, then choice *Keyboard Shortcuts*.

[image: screenshootA]

Now you will have open a window showing all the shortcuts available for the terminal.

Scroll the menu and you will see *Switch to Next Tab*, now double click over this option and press the keys (new shortcut) that you want to.

[image: screenshootB]

Close it and done!

Comment: Whoops, when you hit Ctrl Tab after clicking on New Accelerator it makes an error sound. Maybe Ctrl Tab is reserved?

Comment: @jcollum Unfortunately [any shortcut with TAB cannot be assigned for the gnome terminal](http://askubuntu.com/q/133384/62483) :(

Comment: @Lucio what version of Gnome terminal you have? Mine have that option under Edit > Preferences > Shortcut. Version 3.8.3 is mine :S

Comment: Exactly what option? Mine: *GNOME Terminal 3.6.1*