# How to switch tabs Terminal using Ctrl + Tab?

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal, tabs

Ubuntu 14.04

I know that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Pagedown</kbd>/<kbd>Pageup</kbd> is used for tab switching
Also we can change it in Edit > Keyboard shortcuts.
I want to change the shortcut to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> (forward) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> (previous) but it doesn't let me do so. I am habitual of changing tabs with these keys (as in browsers). Is there anyway to change the shortcut to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>?
So far I am using ` and ~ (exactly above the tab key) for my ease. but tab would be wonderful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been known for years. Referring to [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/162000) bug report from 2007 it says:

> comment from upstream:
>
> "There are a couple of keys which are not candidates to be keyboard
>   accelerators, independently of the modifiers. Tab is one of those
>   keys, as it (with various combinations of modifiers) are reserved by
>   gtk for its own use and the window manager.

In other words, for `gnome-terminal` <kbd>Tab</kbd> is a special key and you cannot use it as part of a shortcut.

The alternative I can suggest is to assign <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to the `xdotool key Ctrl+Page_Down` command.  `xdotool` is a program that allows simulating mouse behavior,key presses, and window controlling functions (very very versatile tool). I have used it quite a lot, so by this point  if it's installed by default, so you will need to install it with `sudo apt-get install xdotool`. Basically you will be pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> but `xdotool` will simulate the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Pg_Down</kbd>. Same idea with the reverse cycling shorcut.

The big disadvantage is that this is a global action, meaning that if some other program has <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> shortcut that isn't for tab switching, it will definitely conflict with that program. Another disadvantage is that you cannot hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and keep on pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> repeatedly. Only the whole shortcut works and once at a time.

Comment: I have made myself used to ctrl + pgup/pgdn. As this works in most apps :)

Comment: For the caveats explained in this answer, the solution at https://askubuntu.com/a/875482/95056 from the referenced bug report is much better.