# Using Tab in an LXTerminal keyboard shortcut?

Tags: shortcut-keys, lxterminal

I'd like to re-map the Next Tab and Previous Tab shortcuts in LXTerminal to match tab switching in my web browser: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, respectively. Unfortunately, there aren't any examples of using the tab key in the other shortcuts in the LXTerminal Preferences window, so I am just trying things blindly.

I've tried `<CTRL>Tab` and even `<CTRL><TAB>`, but every time I try, it simply resets the shortcut to the default value of `<CTRL>Page_Down`.

What is the keyword to use for tab in a shortcut?

FWIW, this is on LXTerminal v0.2.0.

Comment: Issue reported: https://github.com/lxde/lxterminal/issues/16

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is generally not possible to use <kbd>Tab</kbd> in custom shortcuts ('keyboard accelerators') in a GTK2 application like LXTerminal. This appears to be because <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> are reserved for keyboard navigation between user interface controls in GNOME.

Incidentally, the syntax `<CTRL>Tab` is successfully parsed and shown in the application UI if you add it to `.config/lxterminal/lxterminal.conf` (tested in LXTerminal 0.3.0). However, it doesn't achieve the desired effect.

Further reading:

- [Unresolved: Tab for gnome-terminal](http://jennyandlih.com/unresolved-ctrl-tab-gnome-terminal) (jennyandlih.com)
- [Bug 123994 - Need to document: Can't assign ctrl-tab or ctrl-shift-tab in keybindings](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=123994) (GNOME Bugzilla)
- [Keyboard navigation](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/keyboard-nav.html.en) (GNOME Help)
- [keyboard shortcut gnome-terminal (ctrl-tab) and (ctrl-shift-tab) in 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133384/keyboard-shortcut-gnome-terminal-ctrl-tab-and-ctrl-shift-tab-in-12-04) (Ask Ubuntu)
- [How can I bind a key shortcut that includes a tab](https://superuser.com/questions/1088058/how-can-i-bind-a-key-shortcut-that-includes-a-tab) (Super User)
- [gtk_accelerator_parse ()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/2.24/gtk2-Keyboard-Accelerators.html#gtk-accelerator-parse) (GTK+ 2 Reference Manual / Accelerator Groups)