# How to enable touchpad?

Tags: touchpad

Yesterday, suddenly my touchpad on my *MSI Laptop* started to not respond. In other words, in Login screen, touchpad is working as expected. However, *in Desktop screen*, after I have logged in, touchpad is not working.

How can I enable touchpad in Desktop?

Comment: Have you tried, the FN + function key combination?

Comment: Which one ? I am using MSI

Comment: @Mitch make this as answer, it works

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure that the Touchpad is enabled.  On an MSI laptop to Enable or disable the touchpad: <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>.

Answer (score 24):

I accidentally disabled my touchpad. This is the way I found to re-enable it.

Press the "Windows key" to open the start menu. Type "terminal" and enter, to open the command line.

Then type:

```
xinput list
```

Find the 'id' of your touchpad. For me it looks like this:

```
Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

My touchpad has id = 11.

Then type

```
xinput set-prop 11 "Device Enabled" 1
```

(but replace 11 with whatever id your touchpad had)

Comment: in my case I first have to run `xset set-prop ... 0` and then `xset set-prop ... 1` does the job...

Comment: you can use this aliases
alias touchpad-off='xinput set-prop `xinput --list |grep -oP "Touchpad.*id=\K.*?(?=\s)"` "Device Enabled" 0'
alias touchpad-on='xinput set-prop `xinput --list |grep -oP "Touchpad.*id=\K.*?(?=\s)"` "Device Enabled" 1'

Answer (score 20):

This work for me on kali linux:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad send-events
```

The schemas dir can be found by:

```
gsettings list-schemas
```

Edit: This works on Ubuntu 18.04 as well.

Comment: worked for my fujitsu ah512 lifebook. Thankyou

Comment: totally saved me

Comment: This is the only one which works for me in Ubuntu 18.04, to reset changes made to the Enable Touchpad setting in the GNOME settings GUI.

Comment: This worked for Pop!_OS when nothing else did

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Works like a charm on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 14):

Running Ubuntu 16.04 there is a painfully simple way to re-enable the touchpad if you disabled it via the "Mouse & Touchpad GUI":

- <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> to select the "Mouse & Touchpad GUI" if you currently do not have it focused. (Or use the Windows key -> Search for "Mouse and touchpad" -> <kbd>ENTER</kbd>)
- Use <kbd>TAB</kbd> to iterate through the items within the GUI until the ON/OFF slider is highlighted.
- Hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to toggle the switch back to "ON".

I realize this is very simple, but it took me an embarrassingly long time to figure out.

Comment: You sir are the real MVP.

Comment: It's only obvious when you know the answer!

Comment: interestingly, my ubuntu 18 did not show this behaviour, i could not tab across the mouse and touchpoint GUI.. Had to plug a mouse in to re-activate.

Comment: @Hightower that's too bad. I guess this is not something that will work with Ubuntu > 16

Comment: This doesn't work with 19.04 either. Silly interface.

Answer (score 9):

You could try the following command in a terminal and see if it helps, I always used it to restart the touchpad on 11.10 when it stopped working, but I have had no problems on 12.04.

```
synclient Touchpadoff=0
```

Comment: I have tried but touchpad is still not work

Comment: This no longer works under recent Ubuntu since libinput is used.

Comment: I don't know how i disabled the touchpad, but this solved it and it's working again !! Thanks!. You avoid me buying a new laptop ( i was going to smash it).

Comment: @KonradGajewski This still works under Xubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 2):

I don't recall having this problem in 12.04 either but running the `gpointing-device-settings` command and unchecking `Disable touchpad` always did it for me in 11.10.

Comment: I have tried but touchpad is still not work

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Linux Mint and disabled the touchpad, and like others before me, I noticed how hard it is to switch it back on if you don't have a mouse handy.

Using the Mint Preferences to disable the touchpad won't let you enable it again by using xinput or synclient as suggested in various places.

tl;dr

```
gsettings set org.cinnamon.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad touchpad-enabled true
```

Longer version on how I managed to get it back.

I dumped the cinnamon config to a file with:

```
'dconf dump /org/cinnamon/ > mysettings'
```

Under the heading 'settings-daemon/peripherals/touchpad' i found 'touchpad-enabled=false'

List the schemas and find something related to the touchpad

```
gsettings list-schemas | grep touchpad
```

List the keys in the touchpad-schema

```
gsettings list-keys org.cinnamon.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad
```

Enable the touchpad

```
gsettings set org.cinnamon.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad touchpad-enabled true
```

Some useful links:

- [Backing up Cinnamon Settings](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/wiki/Backing-up-and-restoring-your-cinnamon-settings-(dconf))
- [What is dconf and how to use it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22313/what-is-dconf-what-is-its-function-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem but I found the fix for mine to be very simple. I unplugged my mouse out of the USB port on the laptop and the touchpad immediately started working again. It disables the touchpad when you have a mouse plugged in. My Laptop's model is the MSI Apache Pro-012 (GE70)

Answer (score 0):

There is a little button at the bottom of your keyboard on the laptop (sometimes just above the touchpad) mine looks like a W but isn't Windows key, if you have that tiny button it enables and disables your touchpad.