# How do I edit the list of music library locations in Rhythmbox?

Tags: 12.04, rhythmbox

I previously set Rhythmbox to include a few different locations.
Now following changes to my directory structure, I'd like to reflect these changes in Rhythmbox. But when I go to "Library Location", I see "Multiple locations Set" and I can only add to the list; no way to edit/remove.

I Googled this problem and the only relevant results I get date back to 2006, probably referring to a previous version of Rhythmbox and specifying components/locations that I can't find on my system.

Give a look at the documentation...kind of minimal.

Any clues?

Ubuntu 12.04
Rhythmbox 2.96

Comment: A big +1, I wish GNOME people stopped thinking that being able to do simple configuration from GUI is a bad thing.

Answer (score 18):

#### how to...

There are a couple of ways to edit the locations information - either graphically using `dconf-editor` or via the terminal using `gsettings`.

First the graphical way.

Install the package `dconf-tools`.

In the dash press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `dconf-editor`.

Navigate to the position shown in the picture and edit the locations field.

[image]

Note: this is a comma separated list with full path names starting with `file:///` and must be defined with the `['` ... `]'`

Alternatively you can using `gsettings` from the terminal.

Get the current value of the locations field via:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.rhythmbox.rhythmdb locations
```

You should get an output similar to:

```
['file:///home/dad/Music', 'file:///home/dad/.ubuntuone/Purchased%20from%20Ubuntu%20One']
```

To set a new value of the field use the `set` syntax:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.rhythmbox.rhythmdb locations "['file:///home/dad/Music', 'file:///media/musiclibrary/mymusic']"
```

Answer (score 4):

## How to edit Rhythmbox Music Library Locations

Open Rhythmbox and from the menu, select *Edit->Preferences->Music->Library Location*
[image: Edit Rhythmbox Music Library Location]

But unfortunately, Rhythmbox doesn't offer a way to edit the Library Locations when more than one location is set. It just shows **multiple locations set**. To edit multiple Music Library Locations, the easiest way is to use `dconf-tools`. Open `dconf Editor` from Dash or press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `dconf-editor`. Navigate to the the schema *org->gnome->rhythmbox->rhythmdb* and edit the `locations` entry.

[image: Edit Rhythmbox Music Library Locations]

#### Special Case - Removing Ubuntu One Music Library

You'll notice that the *Ubuntu One Music Library* is automatically added to `Library Locations` every time Rhythmbox starts. If you aren't using Ubuntu One Music or don't want to include its library,disable `Ubuntu One Music Plugin` from Rhythmbox. To disable it, open Rhythmbox, from the menu select *Edit->Plugins* and uncheck `Ubuntu One`. Now, remove the Ubuntu One Music Library from Library Locations using any of the methods mentioned above and it won't come back automatically.

[image: Disabling Ubuntu One Music plugin]

---

This method was tried and tested on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with Rhythmbox versions 2.96 and 2.97.