# How do I turn off "show mouse" when I press Ctrl?

Tags: mouse, settings

I've searched everywhere in the system settings but I still can't find it.

Comment: I just found out that `dconf` has replaced `gconf`.  Are you still looking for a fix?

Comment: I will try that later.

Answer (score 32):

***NOTE:*** I found out the `Dconf` has mostly replaced `Gconf`.  Since using `Gconf` did't work, I have updated the instructions for `Dconf`.

You can change the setting in `dconf-editor`

`sudo apt-get install dconf-editor`

Open `dconf-editor` and navigate to: `org -> gnome -> settings-daemon -> peripherals -> mouse`  then check/uncheck the 'locate pointer' option.

[image]

Comment: Didn't work... I have to admit, I did see that on my adventure through every system setting.

Comment: It worked for me and I just add to it the comamndline way( to build in your scripts etc.): `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.mouse locate-pointer true`. Great explanation in http://askubuntu.com/a/191013/79176 .

Comment: This answer is not the best answer for newer versions than at least 15.10

Comment: @MPi Did you try it? It works juts fine for me on 15.10.

Comment: @Seth I did not try it, but it will surely work. My preference would always be a one-liner shell command with pre-installed tools, over a graphical step-by-step explanation with tools to be additionally installed. My comment about the Ubuntu version was probably wrong and misleading, though.

Comment: MPi this worked well for me, versions 14 and 16. Thanks Seth. Installing dconf-editor isn't a big deal it is useful for many, many things. It's useful to have in one's system, or it is for me anyway.

Comment: worked for me on 16.04

Comment: At least with Nautilus 3.14.3 on Ubuntu 16.04 be were of [this bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=125618) that don't let you copy (Ctrl+C) filenames.

Comment: worked for me on ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, gnome 3.28.2

Answer (score 16):

In a terminal run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.mouse locate-pointer true
```

to enable and/or

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.mouse locate-pointer false
```

to disable.

Answer (score 10):

Its under 'Mouse and Touchpad' in System Settings

[image]

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: 12.10, here is a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/nowzZ.png

Comment: Looks like your running Kubuntu.  Is that right?

Comment: No, I'm using gnome 3.6 (with a custom theme, obviously). I think I may have discovered the cause, though. I updated to gnome-control-center 3.6, which doesn't have that option. Any workarounds?

Comment: It looks like linuxmint to me...which would make it off-topic

Comment: @AbrahamVanHelpsing no

Comment: no, thats not it.  I'm running 3.6 too.

Comment: This is what I found, and it looks exactly like what I have: www.webupd8.org/2012/11/gnome-control-center-36-available-in.html. Do you know of any way to downgrade it back to the previous version?

Comment: This thread has the gconf setting.  See if the switch to dconf has nuked this yet: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=949500

Comment: Have to tried accessibility?

Comment: Yes, I've tried practically everything.

Comment: It's a pity that this option has been removed later and as suggested in another answer you now (e.g. Ubuntu 13.10) have to go through a number of steps in **dconf** to this end :-(

Answer (score 4):

## For those in Ubuntu 22.04:

The `Locate Pointer` option is listed in `Settings`->`Accessibility`. Turn it off.

- [Additional reference](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/01/quickly-find-mouse-pointer-ubuntu)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using Gnome Tweak Tool ...

Look at "Keyboard and Mouse" settings ... its an On - OFF switch ... CTRL key.

Comment: -1 because of poor answer. Using GNOME Tweak Tool... in Ubuntu with Unity desktop? There is no "Keyboard and Mouse" settings in GNOME Tweak Tool.

Comment: Still a useful answer, for Ubuntu users on 17.10 that switched to Gnome Shell: `gnome-tweak-tools` > "Keyboard and Mouse" > "Mouse" > "Pointer Location" / "*Press the Ctrl key to highlight the pointer.*"

Comment: its now become valid, and helped me, as i'm on ubuntu 18 - which uses gnome by defaultr

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 20 this setting is in Settings -> Universal Access -> Locate Pointer.

With `dconf`

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/interface/locate-pointer false
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 15.04 LTS

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.mouse locate-pointer true
```

worked fine but I could no longer use the CTRL key in remmina VNC.

Comment: Don't you mean "gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.mouse locate-pointer false"

Answer (score 0):

You can disable using Gnome Tweeks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOXFD.png)