# Linux Equivalent of Windows Ctrl to show Mouse Pointer

Tags: shortcut-keys, mouse

In Windows, it is possible to set pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to display the current location of the mouse pointer, as per [this tutorial](https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/show-pointer-location-with-ctrl-key-in-windows-10.html).

Is there a way of setting a key or key combination to perform the same action in Ubuntu? Note, this is the **opposite** of turning this function off, as detailed at [How do I turn off "show mouse" when I press Ctrl?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230102/how-do-i-turn-off-show-mouse-when-i-press-ctrl).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I turn off "show mouse" when I press Ctrl?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230102/how-do-i-turn-off-show-mouse-when-i-press-ctrl)

Comment: In Xubuntu 19.10 you get mouse cursor visible by Super+F1 by default.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### GNOME based environments (including default Ubuntu)

Open Terminal and run the following command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.mouse locate-pointer true
```

Now if you press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> the pointer should be highlighted.

### KDE

In KDE, go to **System Settings** -> **Desktop Effects** -> **Track Mouse**. Click on the cog icon beside that, and set <kbd>ctrl</kbd> as the modifier key.

Comment: This solution has been a huge pain for me. I turned this feature on early after adopting the Gnome Desktop and didn't realize this was the issue behind my ctlr-* shortcuts being hijacked.  For instance, ctrl-c and ctlr-v don't work as expected because this function overrides them. I was able to work around it by for instance holding down ctrl, then highlighting text I wanted to copy and then copying instead of highlighting and then crtl-c. I rely heavily on shortcuts and this was driving me nuts.

Comment: @RonCollins You can undo this by running `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.mouse locate-pointer false`.

Comment: Btw, No such key “locate-pointer”

Comment: @Snowcrash For newer Ubuntu releases, see this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1271583/480481

Answer (score 13):

It is possible to find this option in the GNOME Tweaks.
Just go to  '**Keyboard & Mouse**' -> '**Pointer Location**' and turn it on/off.

Comment: That workaround is too heavy. Additionally, I would need to see my cursor in first place to navigate there, or just use the keyboard.

Comment: And I bet a bunch it's not in your average Linux distro - e.g. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and don't see those options.

Comment: It is there in 18.04 tweaks but it no longer works (it used to work for a few days, until I played with Appearance, since then I am fighting small cursors and fonts and this "Pointer Location" seems to be dead. This all makes Ubuntu 18 a very bad experience for someone who was used to Ubuntu 16...

Comment: @axd I just occasionally find out it works with `Ctrl + Fn`

Answer (score 7):

In 20.04, this is a slightly different location now for `gsettings` to work with.

In 20.04, this is the `org.gnome.desktop.interface locate-pointer` object.  So:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface locate-pointer true
```

Answer (score 2):

In 20.04, for those who wanted a feature more similar to macOS's one, there's now [Jiggle](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3438/jiggle/) which is a Gnome Shell extension that enlarges your cursor when shaking the mouse.

Once installed, the extension can be configured using GNOME Extensions or GNOME Tweaks.

[GitHub page](https://github.com/jeffchannell/jiggle)

Comment: This works. But there's no guide as to how you change settings like Shake time.

Comment: @Snowcrash, Jiggle's settings can be changed from GNOME Tweaks. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For those using Ubuntu 18.04:

Enable it with Gnome Tweak tools or use the command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.mouse locate-pointer true
```

Then use <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (not just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>).

Comment: VERSION="20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
: No such key “locate-pointer”

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer a graphical way in Ubuntu 20.04 and later, you can go to Settings → *Universal Access* → toggle *Locate pointer* on in the *Pointing & Clicking* section.

[image]