# How do I keep track of the cursor on multiple monitors?

Tags: mouse, display, cursor, accessibility, mouse-pointer

Microsoft or Apple OS has a feature wherein shaking the cursor temporarily enlarges it until you see it, or press Control and a circle will animate around the cursor letting you quickly find it. In Ubuntu 16.04 how do I quickly find the cursor? I frequently lose where it is when using two monitors.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I remember another way, but: in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins
```

then open ccsm using

```
ccsm
```

and enable show mouse, click super+k produces a circular star animation.

Comment: Is there no default option? Must I install this package and its dependencies?

Comment: @DBinJP I feel like there was but I just can't remember.

Comment: @DBinJP a quick google search: https://askubuntu.com/questions/230102/how-do-i-turn-off-show-mouse-when-i-press-ctrl