# Easy way to quickly locate the mouse pointer?

Tags: 16.04, accessibility, mouse-pointer

I am visually impaired, and find it really difficult to locate the mouse pointer on screen. (I am running Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS) Other OS's have built-in methods to make the mouse pointer more easily visible. In Windows you can turn on "pointer trails" where moving the pointer will [leave a trail of pointer images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/harlg.png) making it easier to visually track/follow the pointer. (I nicknamed them "mouse droppings" ;-) ) And in MacOS Sierra, Apple added a feature whereby if you jiggle the mouse pointer (move it back and forth rapidly) it will [temporarily enlarge the mouse pointer](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25507?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US), again to make it easier to see on screen. Is there a similar feature (either built-in or provided by a third-party app) for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 25):

It's not an obvious setting, but you can mimic the Windows behavior of showing the mouse when you press the control key.

### For GNOME based environments

In the terminal, do

```
# Ubuntu 19.10+
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface locate-pointer true

# older versions
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.mouse locate-pointer true
```

Now a little animation will indicate the location of the mouse anytime you tap the <kbd>Control</kbd> key:

[image: control key animation]

(To turn it off, use `false` instead of `true`)

([Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/230113/457562))

### KDE

In KDE, go to `System Settings -> Desktop Effects -> Track Mouse`. Click on the cog icon beside that, and set `Ctrl` as the modifier key.

Comment: No such key “locate-pointer” :( ubuntu 19.10

Comment: @MickeyPerlstein It looks like the command has been changed to ```gsettings org.gnome.desktop.interface locate-pointer true``` in Ubuntu 20.04. However, I can not seem it get this feature working in Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface locate-pointer true` bad key in ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: @GSM-S It only works with left ctrl.

Comment: Ubuntu 20: 

No such key “locate-pointer”
and "Unknown command org.gnome.desktop.interface"

Comment: I'm on Fedora but using Gnome 3 so it ought to be the same.  Rather than messing around with gsettings on the command line, you can go into Control Panel -> Accessibility and under 'Pointing & Clicking' turn on 'Locate Pointer'.
[edit] I'm not visually impaired but run my mouse cursor is so small across my 4k and 1080p monitors that I frequently lose my mouse cursor :)

Comment: The gsettings change does something (and is reflected in the Keyboard & Mouse > Pointer Location toggle in Tweaks), but the animation is very fast, and the circle it makes is only a couple dozen pixels wide, so it's invisible. So I wrote my own: https://gist.github.com/tsbertalan/666cf32a12f7f1e60ddd0e20cf4746a1

Answer (score 0):

> You can do this by enabling **Show mouse** plugin from **CompizConfig
>   Settings manager**. If you don't have them already installed, you
>   can install them from terminal using the following command:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins-extra
> ```
>
> After are installed, open **CompizConfig Settings manager** and enable
>   **Show mouse** plugin. To initiate it use <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> key combination.

This answer is from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/370358/662944). I recommend checking the link (I can't embed images, which is why I recommend checking the link).