# Visually indicate mouse clicks in Gnome 3?

Tags: gnome, mouse, accessibility

I know there is this facility in Ubuntu 18.04/Gnome 3:

- [Linux Equivalent of Windows Ctrl to show Mouse Pointer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/964385/linux-equivalent-of-windows-ctrl-to-show-mouse-pointer)
- [Easy way to quickly locate the mouse pointer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986688/easy-way-to-quickly-locate-the-mouse-pointer?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Basically, when you hit left Ctrl, you can get visual indication that looks like this:

[image: control key animation]

Is there a way to do something similar on every left click of the mouse (and possibly, with a different animation, for right-click of the mouse)?

Comment: Not trolling here but KDE Plasma has color choices for left, middle, and right clicks.

Comment: Still missing feature; we have now an issue open here, https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/5978