# "Shake to Find Cursor" feature for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, gnome, mouse, accessibility, mouse-pointer

Is there any software that does the same as the macOS feature "Shake to Find Cursor" for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Comment: Have not used it in years, so might not be available anymore, but there was something that you could just click 'ctlr' key and it would make circles flash around cursor.  Found this link  https://askubuntu.com/questions/986688/easy-way-to-quickly-locate-the-mouse-pointer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible on Ubuntu **20.04** (GNOME Shell version 3.36.x) using a [GNOME Shell extension](https://askubuntu.com/q/75530/480481) called '**[Jiggle](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3438/jiggle/)**'.

> Jiggle is a Gnome Shell extension that highlights the cursor position when the mouse is moved rapidly.
> [image: jiggle extension]

It provides some customisation options too:
[image: jiggle extension settings]
Besides the '*cursor scaling*' effect (as in the screencast above), it currently provides two more effects: '*fireworks*' and '*spotlight*'.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any software that can do that, but there is an option to make the mouse bigger in *Settings* → *Universal access* → *Cursor size*.

Additionally, you can have your mouse shrinked when hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, just go to *Settings* →  *Universal access* → *Locate pointer*.

Comment: For me, in 20.04, the second option does not shrink the mouse, it just shows a visual clue (concentric circles) to indicate the mouse location. Can you confirm what the case is?

Comment: I think he meant "leave your mouse shrinked" instead of enlarging it like the first suggestion