# Does an extension or option exist to replicate the "shake mouse to find pointer" in Gnome 3?

Tags: unity, gnome-shell, macosx, accessibility, mouse-pointer

Every now and then I fail to track my mouse pointer on a large screen resp. multi monitor setup. MacOS has this nice feature to grow the mouse pointer when shaking the mouse for a bit. Is there any extension or tweak to have this accessibility feature inside Gnome 3?

Comment: There is one extension for newer versions of GNOME Shell: https://askubuntu.com/a/1274965/480481

Answer (score 1):

You could press Ctrl on keyboard and a simple animation will mark the mouse position. If this helps, you can enable it like this:

Open "gnome-tweak-tool" app and go to "keyboard & mouse" tab. Check the "mouse location" button.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I know about the feature but it does not really fit my needs. As a developer I press the Ctrl key quite often, pondering a bit at times. In these cases I find the rings very distracting so I turned it off again.