# XFCE equivalent of a Windows feature: Ctrl to show Mouse Pointer

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, xfce, mouse-pointer

I saw [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/964385/linux-equivalent-of-windows-ctrl-to-show-mouse-pointer) question, but its answers are solely for GNOME, and the highest voted [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/964388/124466) gives the output

```
No such schema “org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.mouse”
```

How to highlight the mouse pointer by pressing  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>  or some other button in XFCE?

[image: winmouse]
 <sup>Similar feature in Windows. [Source](https://www.pdfannotator.com/images/pdfannotator/en/Win10_HighlightCursorPosition_4.png)</sup>

Note: I don't want to lose all the shortcuts related to  <kbd>ctrl</kbd> , as pointed out in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/964385/linux-equivalent-of-windows-ctrl-to-show-mouse-pointer#comment1567826_964388) comment.

Comment: Check [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/230103/124466) out for Unity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XFCE4 on Ubuntu Studio has that feature under "Accessibility" settings:

[image]

You then just need to add a shortcut to `xfce4-find-cursor` in the keyboard shortcuts. You can choose any key you like, including left or right Ctrl. However, it will also activate on any other Ctrl+... combinations then of course.

Comment: Do you know how to change the style of the "visual feedback"?

Comment: No, I'm not sure that's possible.