# Cheese config file location

Tags: cheese

I would like to do a fresh install of cheese. I have purge-removed the package and re-installed but when I open up cheese it has my old settings. Where are the cheese config files located? I would like to remove the cheese config file and I have tried searching for the config file in my home directory with

```
~ $ find -name '*cheese*'
```

But I still can't find it. I am running ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the habit of Gnome applications, Cheese stores its configuration data in the [**dconf**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22313/what-is-dconf-and-what-is-its-function-and-how-do-i-use-it) configuration system rather than in plain files.

To access that, you could use a GUI program called `dconf-editor` from the package [dconf-tools](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-tools) [image: Install dconf-tools Ubuntu package]:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Cheese uses the <s>`/apps/cheese`</s> **`/org/gnome/cheese`**<sup>*(since 14.04)*</sup> gconf path:

[image: Ubuntu Cheese dconf-editor screenshot]

You could easily play with the settings (they all typically have well-documented *schemata* displayed in the bottom of the dconf-editor window), and, ultimately, wipe the  settings clean by **resetting** the values to defaults (non-defaults are highlighted with bold font as you can see on my screenshot).

---

Besides `dconf-editor`, you can also do this from the command line:

<s>`gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.Cheese:/apps/cheese`</s>

**UPD** since I don't know when, that gives an error:

> Schema “org.gnome.Cheese” is not relocatable (path must not be specified)

Which simply asks to call it without the `/apps/cheese` path, like this:

```
gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.Cheese
```

Comment: As of 14.04, the path in dconf-editor that seems to have effect is /org/gnome/cheese. Changing /apps/cheese does not seem to have effect.

Comment: My `cheese` is still broken. I even deleted `~/.config/dconf`. What has gnome done.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor yea... gnome has broken my answer here **again**. But I've retested it, and `gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.Cheese` does reset Cheese settings to defaults.

Comment: I know it is not your fault, but that did not do it. Probably something else broken.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I'd suggest testing with another program; Cheese isn't top-notch and I had it segfaulting. E.g. in VLC, menu Media → Open Capture Device displays camera stream for me, hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. I was going to do that. But could not think of alternative software. It works in VLC. The quest continues.

Comment: There're some recommendations of Cheese alternatives here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/682604/alternatives-to-cheese