# Alternatives to Cheese

Tags: software-recommendation, webcam, cheese

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.04 and I find Cheese very basic, are there any alternatives (I have already read this [Anything better than Cheese for video capture?](https://askubuntu.com/q/186003/364819), however that is only really on video recording, and I would like a balance)?

Specifically, I would like an application which can:

- Record from the webcam
- Take pictures
- Record audio
- Take screencasts (audio recording included in that as well)

Is there a program that can do all this?

Comment: I'd say this is rather opinion based and has no 100% good answer

Comment: @DavidCole: Well, there are many questions like this on the site, and they tend to find at least a good collection of alternatives, so I don't see why this one shouldn't.

Comment: If everyone else on the site said that they were killing themselves, would you too? @ParanoidPanda

Comment: If everyone were being rude to one another, would you? Also http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14394/are-software-recommendations-on-topic-or-not ;)

Comment: @Arronical: No, but this sort of question is generally accepted here.

Comment: I use VLC - [media] - [capture device] `/dev/video0` when I have to put my encounter suit on...  Doesn't do screen casts though...

Comment: @DavidCole When you think something is off topic it's good practise not to answer.

Comment: @David We've finally reopened this, and in light of [our actual policy about this sort of question](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14394/are-software-recommendations-on-topic-or-not), I can't think of a reason it would be off-topic. *So if that's the reason you had deleted your answer, then you may want to undelete it.* `kazam` is still in the repositories for current versions of Ubuntu, and I believe it is useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Camorama**:

Camorama is a small utility to view and save images from a webcam or any other Video4Linux device.
**Installation**:

To install from Software Center click [here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/oneiric/camorama/)

To install from terminal: (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)

```
sudo apt-get install camorama
```

[image]

Alternatively, you may also use [**Vokoscreen**](https://github.com/vkohaupt/vokoscreen) (screenshots included on GitHub page).

**Installation:**

You can Install from Software Centre (Or) from terminal.

To install run:

```
sudo apt-get install vokoscreen
```