# Cheese does not recognize Internal webcam in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, video, webcam, cheese

Cheese does not recognize internal webcam in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Tried Cheese in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and it works flawlessly. Tried executing cheese in the terminal and it displays this error:

```
libv4l2: error setting pixformat: Input/output error

(cheese:27816): cheese-WARNING **: Device '/dev/video0' cannot capture at 1280x720: gstv4l2object.c(3457): gst_v4l2_object_set_format_full (): /GstCameraBin:camerabin/GstWrapperCameraBinSrc:camera_source/GstBin:bin18/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src1:Call to S_FMT failed for BGR3 @ 1280x720: Input/output error
```

Cheese displays "There was an error displaying video from the webcam".

And whenever I try to change the resolution in Preferences, Cheese does not show any options in the menu. I click on "Cheese" to open the menu but nothing shows up:

[image of Cheese not displaying options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BfZy.png)

Any tips on how I can solve the problem?

Comment: Go into the Cheese preferences, and set both the photo and video resolution to a lower value, such as 640x480, and restart Cheese. Does that fix the problem ?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response! I tried to change the resolution but Cheese does not display any options in the menu. Is there another way to change the resolution? I edited the initial post with an image. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have a look at this: [Cheese config file location](http://askubuntu.com/q/233063), you can change the values `video-x-resolution` and `video-y-resolution` (shown in the screenshot of the answer there) to 640 and 480 respectively. Also note the comment on the answer.

Comment: In Ubuntu 14.04 LTS it worked  with 1280x720. I changed the resolution in 16.04, but I ended with the same error:                                                                                                                              libv4l2: error setting pixformat: Input/output error

(cheese:7000): cheese-WARNING **: Device '/dev/video0' cannot capture at 640x480: gstv4l2object.c(3457): gst_v4l2_object_set_format_full (): /GstCameraBin:camerabin/GstWrapperCameraBinSrc:camera_source/GstBin:bin18/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src1:
Call to S_FMT failed for BGR3 @ 640x480: Input/output error

Comment: In that case, I don't know what the problem could be, sorry. But there's other applications which you can use as an alternative to cheese, though.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in gstreamer fixed in version 1.14.2: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=796789.

I fixed it by manually downloading the relevant packages for cosmic, that have already been updated to use this version. So something like:

```
mkdir tmp
cd tmp
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gst-plugins-good1.0/1.14.2-1ubuntu3/+build/15172738/+files/libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0_1.14.2-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gst-plugins-good1.0/1.14.2-1ubuntu3/+build/15172738/+files/gstreamer1.0-plugins-good_1.14.2-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```