# how to configure file naming in Cheese

Tags: webcam, cheese, naming

the timed 'burst' photos taken by cheese are named year-month-day-time_1 then _2, _3,..._10,_11 etc..
How can I configure file naming to be year-month-day-time_0001, _0002, etc.. so that the sequence stays the same when importing as block in to other programs (so that they don't get re-ordered into _1, _10, _11 ...)

examples of file names are 2017-02-26-173350_1.jpg or 2017-02-26-173350_121.jpg and I'd like to change the number after underscore to fixed 3 digit so that _1 becomes _001 and _121 stays _121.

In 'burst' Cheese date-time stamp names its first file and uses the same date name followed by _'number' for all subsequent photos. Now I'm thinking maybe the best way to batch rename is with the true time each file was made? If so, here too scripting would be helpful. Thank you! Leslie

Comment: Cheese doesn't have configuration for that. The only options available care via particular `dconf` schema, which you can see here: http://askubuntu.com/a/233083/295286  If you don't mind alternatives, it's always possible to write a script that will rename all files in a batch

Comment: thank you Serg. options indeed do not cover file naming (pity). I'm new to Linux and just learning my way around the console. Looked at many posts/questions on batch renaming scripts, none seem quite to answer. Do you know of one that would allow me to have a fixed 'decimal' point after _ , so that 1 is converted to 001; 23 to 023 and 3 digit numbers remain as they are?

Comment: I can certainly provide, but I don't quite understand `converted to 001; 23 to 023 and 3 digit numbers remain as they are` . Can you click edit button under your question and provide a working example, with original filename and the one you wish to have as result ?