# Cheese: How to save camera image with another format (other than .jpg)?

Tags: 20.04, file-format, cheese

I'm tring to use builtin webcam from my laptop to capture image.
Currently I'm using cheese. I know **vlc** will do the job but I wonder if **cheese** can do this.

I haven't found any option to change saving image format, both in **preference** or **cheese config file**.
How can I save image with image formats with **low data loss**, such as .bmp or .png

Comment: Cheese will only make an image with maximum resolution same as the screen or camera. This will likely be 1024x1080, see: https://askubuntu.com/a/17278/43926. PNG and JPEG will compress this image, BMP will not. 1024x1080 is 1024x1080 no matter what format it is in.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm not seeking a higher resolution. In fact, the data compress you mentioned is the thing I worried for now. I wonder if I can save image in low data loss format. Such as .bmp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cheese apparently can't do this in the current version.

The [source code](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/cheese/-/blob/master/libcheese/cheese-fileutil.h) looks as if the file extension '.jpg' is hard-coded.

So if you want to change that, you could start with an issue at https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/cheese/-/issues.
And if you know C, then you could even provide a merge request there.

However, there are other programs that take snapshots in lossless formats and can be used from the command line interface, e.g. gucview:

```
guvcview -i my_image1.png -g none -e -t 1 -n 1
```

This creates a single snapshot (see `guvcview --help` for details).

According to [another stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391456/take-picture-from-webcam-using-linux-command-line-bash#comment11866923_9391503), vlc can also be used from the command line:

```
vlc -I dummy v4l2:///dev/video0 --video-filter scene --no-audio --scene-path /tmp --scene-prefix image_prefix --scene-format png vlc://quit --run-time=1
```

seems to save many snapshots until you abort the process with ctrl-c. (The last two params seem to be ignored in my system.)

Answer (score -2):

### Saving Image Files to Another Format

**LibreOffice Draw** will open: BMP, EMF, GIF, JPEG, PCX, PGM, PMB, PNG, PPM, PSD, RAS, SVG, TIFF, TGA, WMF, ETC

LibreOffice Draw will export: BMP, EMF, EPS, GIF, JPEG, PNG, SVG, TIFF AND WMF.

LibreOffice Draw will provide options when exporting such as Size, Resolution, Color Depth, Quality and will tell you the file size.

LibreOffice Draw comes packaged with Ubuntu.

Comment: Sorry, I should be clear. I'm using software form Ubuntu **cheese** that works with my webcam

Comment: Converting to another format isn't really going to help, if the original image was saved as JPG.

Comment: I think the best cheese can do is match your screen or camera resolution, This would likely be 1280x1024. PNG will compress this image, BMP will not.  see: https://askubuntu.com/a/233083/43926

Comment: 1280x1024 is 1280x1024 no matter how you look at it.