# Are dconf schema names case-sensitive?

Tags: dconf, gsettings

I have found an example of a schema that is referred two in two different ways, differing only in case, which is confusing to me.

Gsettings sees the schema name as `com.canonical.Unity.Launcher`, and does not accept `com.canonical.unity.launcher` as a valid schema name. On the other hand, dconf-editor only sees `com.canonical.unity.launcher` all lower-case, as seen in the screenshot.

If I change the key `favorites` in Gsettings, that change is reflected in dconf-editor, and vice-versa.

What's going on? Which is the correct schema name, `com.canonical.Unity.Launcher`, or `com.canonical.unity.launcher`?

#### Gsettings:

```
$ gsettings list-schemas | grep -i com.canonical.unity.launcher
com.canonical.Unity.Launcher
david@david-Aspire-5735:~$ $ gsettings list-recursively com.canonical.Unity.Launcher
com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorite-migration '3.2.10'
com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites ['application://firefox.desktop', 'application://thunderbird.desktop', 'unity://running-apps', 'unity://expo-icon', 'unity://devices']
david@david-Aspire-5735:~$ gsettings list-recursively com.canonical.unity.launcher
No such schema 'com.canonical.unity.launcher'
```

#### dconf-editor:

[image: Screenshot of dconf-editor, cropped]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shouldn't dconf-editor and gsettings access the same database?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/416556/shouldnt-dconf-editor-and-gsettings-access-the-same-database)

Comment: I respect that is one older then the one I mention. But thought the newer one gives more references and better background info about this case. (If you, Flimm & @whtyger, agree with me)

Comment: That question seems useful but not a duplicate of this one. This question is very specificly about case sensitivity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dconf schema tree is tricky and not always relevant to actual schema names.

For example, under `apps` you can find `update-manager`, but you will not find `apps.update-manager` schema using gsettings. Valid schema name is `com.ubuntu.update-manager`, and it isn't shown in Dconf where it actually should be. Correct schema name in Dconf can be found below the keys list, at the grey field with Description and Default value. (See screenshot) Topmost entry shows real Schema name.

So I'd trust gsettings output. In your case `com.canonical.Unity.Launcher` is the valid schema name and its case really matters.

[image: Screenshot highlighting schema field]

Comment: Interesting, I didn't notice the schema field in dconf-editor. If the tree path doesn't always match the schema name, what does it match?

Comment: Maybe these schema names were changed during development process and weren't fixed in dconf frontend yet. Or simply forgotten. There are also several dconf settings that have no schema at all. `org>gtk>settings>file-chooser`, for example. I wonder how they can be changed using gsettings?

Comment: BTW, these options without schemas can be changed using `dconf` in terminal. Check `dconf --help` for all options. For example, `dconf write /org/gtk/settings/file-chooser/show-hidden true` turns option on. Autocompletion of the key name works also when typing in terminal. Cool!