# Accidentally hid a notification in xfce4-notifyd

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

I use Xubuntu 13.10. Yesterday I accidentally hid a notification that shows if my vpn connection was successful. I clicked on the button "Never show this notification again" or so....It is a guess that xfce4-notifyd shows these notifications.

Is there a way to undo this action? Perhaps a config file or something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My answer is based on [Mik](https://askubuntu.com/users/76204/mik)'s<sup>**</sup> very thorough response here: [What is dconf, what is its function, and how do I use it?](https://askubuntu.com/a/191013/25656).

I'm assuming that your Xubuntu is a default one and that you are using Network Manager with nm-applet.

To reverse the action of clicking "Never show this notification again", open your terminal and paste in the following:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.nm-applet disable-vpn-notifications
```

The status will be returned to you. In my case, the response is "false".

In your case, to revert to seeing the notifications again, now paste in the following:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nm-applet disable-vpn-notifications false
```

Alternatively, you could just reset the value to the default by using:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.nm-applet disable-vpn-notifications
```

You may need to disable networking and renable it or log off and log in again or reboot for the changes to take effect.

---

Edit: there is a GUI if you want to avoid using the terminal. It's called `dconf editor` and you can get it from the software center or by running:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Again, Mik's answer describes its usage but, at least in the past, there have been instances of confusion: an example is here: [Are dconf schema names case-sensitive?](https://askubuntu.com/a/244302/25656).

**Mik has asked for his account to be deleted according to [this](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/8177/25656).