# How to renable “never show” notifications in Xubuntu 14.04?

Tags: xubuntu, notification

Dear beloved community!

I accidentally disabled some applications from the notifications bubble. I was wondering, how can I renable the hidden applications again? I found a few answers on askubuntu and the ubuntu forums, but unfortunately the information no longer corresponds properly to the actual file system (e.g: dconf-editor -> apps -> nm-applet -> "disable-connected-notifications" and "disable-disconnected-notifications" are disabled "unchecked", does no longer apply, I can't see anything in there except stamp = value 3).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Have a nice day!

Comment: forgive me for asking, but what is the notifications bubble?

Comment: I don't know what to call it lol, I guess it's the notification pop-up on the top right hand side of the screen. Like for example, you connect to the internet, and a pop-up displays that you are now connected..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this commands to reset the values from command-line:

Network notifications:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.nm-applet disable-connected-notifications
gsettings reset org.gnome.nm-applet disable-disconnected-notifications
```

Wireless notifications:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.nm-applet disable-wifi-create     
gsettings reset org.gnome.nm-applet suppress-wireless-networks-available
```

VPN notifications

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.nm-applet disable-vpn-notifications
```

Thanks for this hint to https://askubuntu.com/a/398488/265974

Or with the dconf-editor:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I just reseted my notifications and it's all fine and dandy now :-)! You are awesome!