# Shortcuts no longer work for move window to left/right of screen in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, unity, shortcut-keys, window

I used to be able to send windows to the left/right half of the screen with ctrl-windows-left and ctrl-windows-right in 12.04. Now the left/right shortcuts do not work, but ctrl-windows-up / down still work as they used to (maximise, minimise)

EDIT: couple of Ubuntu updates later and it appears to be working again without my having to change anything.

Comment: Are you running 13.04 now?

Comment: Nope, still on 12.04. I'm guessing this happened with recent updates.

Comment: This problem just appeared for me in 14.04 :(

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Workes for me with 16.04

Comment: Maybe this: https://askubuntu.com/a/822044/309223
will answer your question?

Answer (score 5):

The `System Settings` menu has a `Keyboards` item that you can use to re-bind the shortcut:

[image]

Comment: I can't spot the action that I want to bind those shortcuts to though. I want the equivalent of Windows-left and Windows-right in M$ Windows - i.e. resize the window to half the available screen space and move to the left (or right). This is different from moving to a different workspace.

Comment: Sorry I missed the requirement for half screen space. BTW - what you want works for me in Unity with 13.04. I'll see if I can find the key bindings file somewhere on my system.

Answer (score 2):

It might be worth checking the following `dconf` seettings:

- `move-to-side-e`
- `move-to-side-w`.

They can be found in the following path `org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings`.

[image]

- [What is dconf, what is its function, and how do I use it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22313/what-is-dconf-what-is-its-function-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Comment: that's still moving between desktops, while author was looking for a way to automatically resize the window to occupy left or right half of the same desktop.