# Ctrl + Super + Left/Right not working in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: unity, 16.04

I used to use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd> / <kbd>Right</kbd> before to split my screen space in two windows. It suddenly stopped working. In System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts, I do see an option to add a key binding along with a command, but what would that command be?

Comment: screen space of the desktop or any specific application?

Comment: Desktop, like the unity desktop

Comment: never  saw this shortcut before!  were you using this in unity or gnome shell?

Comment: @Anwar this is Unity shortcut for snapping windows to half the screen

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The grid plugin of compiz is responsible for window placement via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow Right/Left</kbd>. For whatever reason, you may not have it enabled.

Install Compiz Config Settings Manager with `sudo apt-get install  compizconfig-settings-manager` and ensure that `Grid` is checked just like in the screenshot below 
[image]

Comment: Thanks - I just had this issue and your answer fixed it. I am curious, however, why they the ctrl+super+(left or right) would suddenly stop working and needs to be set again in compiz?

Comment: @DarrenHaynes That I don't know.  It's one of the peculiarities of compiz. Among most nasty ones is when Unity plugin gets unset, and user ends up with bare desktop and no launcher or top panel. And there's plenty of solutions for that, but again - no explanation as to why this happens and what might cause it

Comment: Somehow on my nearly fresh installation of 16.04, the shortcuts weren't working, as in OP's question. I looked in CCSM and found that "Grid" was already checked. By clicking into Grid and and then the Bindings tab, I found that the left/right maximize bindings were set to e.g. <Control><Alt>Left, although they didn't work (presumably because the Desktop Wall commands for switching workspaces had higher priority). I changed the shortcuts to e.g. <Control><Super>Left, and now they work.

Comment: @Cerran Changing the shortcut to something with `<Super>` didn't work for me because compiz refused to accept the `<super>` key. Posted a question on the subject: [Values cannot be changed in CompizConfig System Manager (CCSM) when using <super>](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1008036/values-cannot-be-changed-in-compizconfig-system-manager-ccsm-when-using-super)

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka Interesting. My issue was on a Dell variant of Ubuntu, as well, so it seems that they are doing something strange that messes up these default key bindings.

Comment: In my case it happened on Artful when somehow I got a messed up Unity after a logout&login, then when trying to restart system I didn't bother to wait till it completes whatever made it hanging (closing some session or something) and hit Magic SysRq. That for some arcane reason forced compiz to lose the Grid setting as per this answer. And I can't work without these shortcuts. What a PITA!