# how to re-enable OpenGL

Tags: compiz, opengl

I was trying to speed up my tiny laptop by switching off OpenGL using Compiz.  I guess there were also whole bunch of related plugins got disabled in the process.  Then I lost the entire GUI desktop interface.

Could someone please tell me how to get everything back through command line?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you type anything of this 1. ctrl+alt+t 2. ctrl+F2

Comment: After a few reboots, I could login to Guess session with GUI, but my own account can't even login.  It will loop back to the login screen.

Answer (score 3):

**ON UBUNTU 14.04**

1. Switch to tty1 using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
2. Login to your user account
3. And export your Display with

   ```
   export DISPLAY=:0
   ```
4. Add `opengl` to Compiz active plugins list

   ```
   dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/active-plugins "[`dconf read /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/active-plugins | sed -r 's/(\[|\])//g'`, 'opengl']"
   ```

   Or reset the key to default

   ```
   dconf reset /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/active-plugins
   ```

   If it didn't work, come back and reset all Compiz settings to defaults

   ```
   dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
   ```
5. Restart graphical display manager after one of the dconf command above

   ```
   sudo service lightdm restart
   ```
6. Switch back to tty7 (X graphic display) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>

Try login again.

---

However, Compiz `ccsm` applies changes instantly so may be it's a nice habit to make configuration backup before change.

- Backup before change:

  ```
  dconf dump /org/compiz/ > compiz.dconf
  ```
- Restore if things went wrong:

  ```
  dconf load /org/compiz/ < compiz.dconf
  ```
- Sometimes it is helpful to monitor the changes: `dconf watch /org/compiz/`

Reference:

- [`man dconf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man1/dconf.1.html)
- [What is dconf, what is its function, and how do I use it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22313/what-is-dconf-what-is-its-function-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Comment: Thanks.  Reinstalled Ubuntu already but thanks for your help.  Now I know how to switch between tty and reenable things in Compiz.

Comment: Ok, I added some info which may help others with similar problem.