# How to store network-manager settings in home

Tags: wireless, networking, 14.04, network-manager, security

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with the `network-manager`. It stores all Information about wireless networks, VPNs, ... in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` and I was just wondering why... I thought the home folder of each user should contain all configuration files, especially those with security-relevant information. I'm using an encrypted home directory and want this information to be encrypted, too.

Is there any other directory (in the home folder) where the `network-manager` reads configuration files from (after login!)

Comment: This is an excellent question without a good answer so far. It is crazy that something as sensitive as a user's home wifi password should be stored in `/etc` and not the user's `home` space

Answer (score 1):

It's stored there because "All users may connect to this network"
ticked on that Wifi connection point. Open network indicator -> Edit
connections ... -> Select network -> Click edit... -> in general tab
untick "All users may connect to this network".

[SOURCE](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-discuss/2013-December/014807.html)

Comment: No that is not the case. This is already unticked for all connections, but the configuration files are still in the same directory

Comment: You can follow [this](https://echt.guth.so/moving-networkmanager-config-files-to-home/) guide if you want to put them in the home foder.   But a Ubuntu developer pointed out that this workaround might introduce a security whole when an attacker has access to your running system. You can read about that in the Source of the answer.

Comment: Pabi's last comment refers to a now dead link, here is a Wayback Machine version http://web.archive.org/web/20131230014629/http://echt.guth.so/moving-networkmanager-config-files-to-home/

Answer (score 0):

Though settings for the user are stored in the home directory, settings for the system such as the network configuration, some power management, laptop display brightness etc are stored in the system configuration directories, in `/etc` and other places.

Some settings, like the proxy being used, are stored in [`dconf`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22313/what-is-dconf-what-is-its-function-and-how-do-i-use-it) - you can view this in [`dconf-tools`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-tools/), or for instance the settings for the proxy mode by running:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.system.proxy mode
```

Comment: yes, but why should network credentials be considered as system wide settings instead of user specific settings?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo mv /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections /home/you
sudo ln -s /home/you/system-connections /etc/NetworkManager
```

Agreed that this should definitely be user config, at least optionally.