# Where are the settings modified by "unity-tweak-tool" stored?

Tags: unity, 14.04, system-settings, automation, unity-tweak-tool

Where are the settings as modified by "unity-tweak-tool" stored?

Can they be edited with a text editor?

Is there documentation, manual or help on the available options?
Are there options not available in the GUI? which? 
Where is the documentation available?

Are there system wide pre-sets possible?
Are there automation guidelines?

This question is different from this [What is dconf, what is its function, and how do I use it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22313/what-is-dconf-what-is-its-function-and-how-do-i-use-it)
because unity-tweak-tool is not mentioned there, and thus that question and answer can not be found by simply search for unity-tweak-tool.

Comment: There are many kinds of setting which unity-tweak-tool can modify them, but those setting are stored in many places, not in one place  as you may think and edit them  with a text editor.

Comment: This question pretty much sums up what you need to know: http://askubuntu.com/questions/22313/what-is-dconf-what-is-its-function-and-how-do-i-use-it. The dconf system is quite similar in concept to the Windows-Registry if you are from that background.

Comment: Also see the official GNOME dconf site for documentation and other details: http://live.gnome.org/dconf

Comment: `gsettings` and `dconf` may help you!

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to that information. Apparently I have been marked with impending ban. Because this question was my only one and it is marked as duplicate by multiple members. I just wanted to point out that it is not fair marking a question as duplicate if the keyword is not mentioned in the question of which it is supposed to be a duplicate

Comment: Marking a question as duplicate is not the same as a condemnation of the poster, it is simply a way to make sure the work that has already been done isn't wasted. Naming a question is an art on itself, and many questions are indeed hard to find if it where for their title.