# How to configure tracker-extract so it has a higher nice value?

Tags: gnome, 15.10, tracker

I suffer each time I return from a pause and I find my desktop stalled because the priority of tracker-extract consumes too much CPU (sometimes 104%), so I have to kill thru terminal the task (tracker-miner-fs, tracker-extract, and tracker-store) in order to return to my regular desktop activities.

I understand the importance of this program, but I do not want to solve its niceness issue every time by hand. And I do not want to remove it definetely.

Is there a configuration file so I can set it to my personal taste (I will choose a higher value so it really executes on a low priority level)?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tracker's settings are now on [dconf database](https://askubuntu.com/a/191013/349837), Managed through `dconf-editor` (GUI) or `gsettings` (CLI) under the `org.freedesktop.Tracker.*` tree:

[image: screenshot]

For Ubuntu 16.04, you could set indexing to run in the background with  `tracker-preferences`. If that command wasn't already installed, you could install it with `sudo apt install tracker-gui`

After its initial complete index run, `tracker` — at least on a machine with SSD storage that isn't receiving huge dumps of new files — shouldn't take a significant time to run. If you find that tracker has locked up, I have suggested a solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/914581/no-progress-updates-from-gnome-tracker/914602#914602).

Comment: Although you are correct, it would have been helpful to the questioner if you had explained that to access the tracker-preferences, they should `sudo apt-get install tracker-gui`

Comment: @DavidFoerster  I was way to busy playing with the new set of settings!

Comment: @scruss Thank you! Your answer is supercomplete. I also checked yourlink to the solution, which is exactly what I need to understand tracker issues.

Comment: `tracker-gui` is [only present on 16.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=tracker-gui)

Comment: Seems so,  @PabloBianchi. Settings now seem to be in `gsettings`

Comment: Did you know which key on dconf db is related to tracker-extract niceness/priority/CPU usage?

Comment: @PabloBianchi You have to set `sched-idle` to 'always'.