# no progress updates from gnome tracker

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-gnome, 17.04, cpu-load, tracker

I very much want to have desktop search working on a new Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 installation. I realize that initial indexing might take a while, but for more than 12 hours, `tracker status` has returned:

```
Currently indexed: 93634 files, 6371 folders
Remaining space on database partition: 226.6 GB (45.10%)
Data is still being indexed: Estimated less than one second left
```

There should be more than 94000 files indexed, after excluded files have been removed. I can't tell if the process has crashed, or is still working on files.

`tracker daemon` has returned the same result all this time:

```
Store:
12 May 2017, 15:45:13:  ✓     Store                 - Idle 

Miners:
12 May 2017, 15:45:13:  ✓     Userguides            - Idle 
12 May 2017, 15:45:13:  ✓     File System           - Idle 
12 May 2017, 15:45:13:    0%  Extractor             - Extracting metadata 
12 May 2017, 15:45:13:  ✓     Applications          - Idle
```

and using the `-f` and `-w` options return no updates. `tracker-extract` is using one of my cores at 100% and has been all of this time.

How can I tell if tracker is having problems or just taking its time indexing roughly 200 GB of files?

Comment: Running `tracker daemon -f` as soon as I could after a reboot, I did see updates about *File System           - Crawling recursively directory ...* that have now fallen idle.  Extractor is *still* extracting metadata, which may be the problem

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It seems that `tracker-extract` was having problems with a couple of Excel XLS files from the same auto-generated source. I suspect they were hitting bugs in tracker's extract code. Tracker has now successfully indexed, and is using negligible resources.

This Debian User Forums post was the key: [will tracker-extract ever settle down?](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=131284). Diagnosing and fixing the problem required me to look in `/tmp/tracker-extract-files.1000`. If a symlink to the same file persists for any amount of time and `tracker-extract` is hitting 100% CPU usage, you have a problem file. For me, a problem file symlink looked like:

```
$ ls -l tracker-extract-files.1000/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 scruss scruss 55 May 12 16:25 1-9eaf433878d0c8e604486b798d035882 -> /home/scruss/Documents/toronto_hydro/SmartMeterData.xls
```

To fix this particular file:

- stop tracker with `tracker daemon --terminate`
- Resave the offending file in a different format, delete it, or set it as excluded in the tracker config GUI. It's important that the file with problems is *gone* from anywhere that tracker will try to index, or the problem will persist.
- Delete the broken symlink in `/tmp/tracker-extract-files.1000`
- restart tracker with `tracker daemon --start`

If you monitor tracker with `tracker daemon --follow`, you should see Extractor progress lines increase from 0, 1, 2 ... 100%. If it hangs at anything less than 100%, check `/tmp/tracker-extract-files.1000` again.

For me, `tracker-extract` used to throw the error *tracker-extract crashed with signal 31 in __libc_message()* when it finished. It didn't seem to affect tracker running or indexing new content, though.

Comment: That was most helpful, thank you ! I could pinpoint the culprit. A "playsid" file from a huge C64 collection. Cheers !

Comment: @mahen I just had to refer back to this post to fix a block tracker miner, And sure enough, the offending file was "Lunatico_Side_2.sid" from CSDB …

Comment: Thanks for this. I had the tracker choke on an .exr file created by Meshroom. That caused my Ryzen 3700 to not go into idle, so it remained at 60°C. Now it goes as low as 40°C again after adding exceptions via dconf editor under `org/freedesktop/tracker/miner/files`.

Comment: In *yet more fun with tracker* news, on one of my systems it had forgotten how to find things despite large databases in ~/.cache/tracker. `tracker daemon --follow` showed **✗ Store - Unavailable**. A brute-force solution appears to be `tracker daemon --terminate`, followed by `tracker reset --hard` (it's interactive, so you can't chain these commands), followed by `tracker daemon --start`. This will force the reindexing of your whole system, so is not ideal