# How to disable tracker on ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: intel-cpu

I purchased a new acer i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz × 8 laptop installed ubuntu 20.04 along with dual boot Windows. Whenever I start the laptop either in windows or ubuntu both are making very loud noise. I suspected fan was faulty so I gave it to replace it. Now the laptop came with replaced fan still it is creating too loud unbeareable noise.
When I see the processes via top more than 100% cpu consumption is going on for tracker-miner-f and tracker-extract for at least more than half an hour.
Please let me know what should I do get rid of this noise? You can see the screenshots of top command here.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVMpf.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5ZIP.png)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1172237/why-is-tracker-miner-fs-consuming-100-of-my-cpu-what-is-usr-lib-tracker-track

Comment: also see  https://askubuntu.com/questions/346211/tracker-store-and-tracker-miner-fs-eating-up-my-cpu-on-every-startup

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tracker process taking lot of CPU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187191/tracker-process-taking-lot-of-cpu)

Answer (score 21):

Even if you disable all the `Search` functions in settings, the tracker stuff still runs. I don't have any use for it so I have found the following two commands seem to disable everything for me. I have not noticed any issues by doing this:

`tracker reset --hard`

`systemctl --user mask tracker-{miner-apps,miner-fs,store}`

Comment: UPDATE: For later Ubuntu versions (22.04 onwards I think) that use tracker 3 I am now doing this: `systemctl --user mask tracker-extract-3.service tracker-miner-fs-3.service tracker-miner-rss-3.service tracker-writeback-3.service tracker-xdg-portal-3.service tracker-miner-fs-control-3.service` followed by `tracker3 reset -s -r`

Comment: For Ubuntu 22.04 masking the services my be not enough. You probably have files in `/etc/xdg/autostart/` like `/etc/xdg/autostart/tracker-miner-fs-3.desktop`, so you need to "override" this file and make sure it will not be started: Create `~/.config/autostart/tracker-miner-fs-3.desktop` content
`[Desktop Entry]\nHidden=true` (`\n` being a new line, because I can not post that in this comment here ;) and after logout/login the process should not be started anymore (also `tracker3 daemon` will show it disabled)

Comment: Verified testing this on 20.04/21.04 (Xubuntu) and it seems to work. In fact it seems things perform better without this. I don't rely on indexing, I have my own system of keeping track of my files, and don't rely at all on the "dummy light" stuff, which I imagine is what this is. Kinda how like I don't rely on the oil light in my car to tell me when I need to check the oil.

Answer (score 5):

Make tracker-miner-fs, tracker-extract,tracker-store non executables.
It's a workaround but it works.

```
sudo chmod -x /usr/libexec/tracker-miner-fs
sudo chmod -x /usr/libexec/tracker-extract
sudo chmod -x /usr/libexec/tracker-store
```

Comment: In Ubuntu 22.04, just `sudo chmod -x /usr/libexec/tracker-miner-fs-3` seems to work nicely.

Answer (score 4):

Source: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Tracker

**Disabling tracker globally (for all users)**

**for Ubuntu 22 LTS**

- Edit `/etc/xdg/autostart/tracker-miner-fs-3.desktop` file with root priviledges
- Add `Hidden=true` to the end of the file

**for older Ubuntu versions**

- Edit `/etc/xdg/autostart/trackerd.desktop` file with root privileges
- Add `Hidden=true` to the end of the file
- Do the same for `/etc/xdg/autostart/tracker-applet.desktop` if you want

**Disabling tracker for current user only**

**for Ubuntu 22 LTS**

- Not tested (instructions for older Ubuntu versions may work, please comment)

**for older Ubuntu versions**

- Enter the directory `~/.config/autostart`, create it if it does not exist
- Create a file named `trackerd.desktop`
- Paste the following into the file, save and exit

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Tracker
Hidden=true
```

Comment: On Debian 11 (Bullseye) `/etc/xdg/autostart/tracker-miner-fs.desktop` and `/etc/xdg/autostart/tracker-extract.desktop` seem to be the relevant files.

Comment: This did not work for me on 22.04 (Linux 5.19.0-41-generic x86_64), but making the 3 files non-executable as mentioned in another comment did work.

Comment: By way of explanation, the [Desktop Entry Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html) defines this key-value pair as follows

"Hidden should have been called Deleted. It means the user deleted (at their level) something that was present (at an upper level, e.g. in the system dirs). It's strictly equivalent to the .desktop file not existing at all, as far as that user is concerned. This can also be used to "uninstall" existing files (e.g. due to a renaming) - by letting make install install a file with Hidden=true in it."