# I'm using Ubuntu 22.04. Every time I create a new react app, tracker-miner-fs-3 starts to eat up 100% CPU

Tags: 22.04, tracker

I tried to remove tracker cache by running `rm -r ~/.cache/tracker3`, it works, but when I create a new react app(using `npx create-react-app`), it starts to use 100% CPU again. What can I do to solve this issue so that I don't have to clear tracker cache every time I use react.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want/need tracker3? You could disable tracker3, see my comment on a post [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1344050/how-to-disable-tracker-on-ubuntu-20-04/1344067#1344067) regarding how to disable tracker3. Or maybe try a regular cron job to do the tracker3 reset it if you don't want to disable it?