# tracker-miner-fs crashes on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, tracker

I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 today, and after this upgrade tracker-miner-fs seems to crash and restart contiguously; pegging my CPU at 100% until I manually kill the process.

The error I'm getting in `/var/log/syslog` is:

```
Apr 28 22:23:01 evertbook5 tracker-miner-f[31182]: Could not find parent node for URI:'file:///home/evert/Music/unsorted/iTunes%20Music/Giorgio%20Moroder/E=MC2'
Apr 28 22:23:01 evertbook5 tracker-miner-f[31182]: NOTE: URI theme may be outside scheme expected, for example, expecting 'file://' when given 'http://' prefix.
Apr 28 22:23:01 evertbook5 tracker-miner-f[31182]: tracker_file_system_set_property: assertion 'file != NULL' failed
Apr 28 22:23:01 evertbook5 tracker-miner-f[31182]: tracker_file_system_set_property: assertion 'file != NULL' failed
Apr 28 22:23:01 evertbook5 tracker-miner-f[31182]: Could not find parent node for URI:'file:///home/evert/Music/unsorted/iTunes%20Music/Giorgio%20Moroder/E=MC2/08%20Evolution.mp3'
Apr 28 22:23:01 evertbook5 tracker-miner-f[31182]: NOTE: URI theme may be outside scheme expected, for example, expecting 'file://' when given 'http://' prefix.
Apr 28 22:23:01 evertbook5 tracker-miner-f[31182]: tracker_file_system_set_property: assertion 'file != NULL' failed
Apr 28 22:23:01 evertbook5 tracker-miner-f[31182]: tracker_file_system_set_property: assertion 'file != NULL' failed
Apr 28 22:23:02 evertbook5 tracker-miner-fs[31182]: **
Apr 28 22:23:02 evertbook5 tracker-miner-fs[31182]: Tracker:ERROR:../src/libtracker-miner/tracker-file-system.c:259:file_tree_lookup: assertion failed: (ptr[0] == '/')
Apr 28 22:23:02 evertbook5 tracker-miner-fs[31182]: Bail out! Tracker:ERROR:../src/libtracker-miner/tracker-file-system.c:259:file_tree_lookup: assertion failed: (ptr[0] == '/')
Apr 28 22:23:02 evertbook5 systemd[2738]: tracker-miner-fs.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=6/ABRT
Apr 28 22:23:02 evertbook5 systemd[2738]: tracker-miner-fs.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
Apr 28 22:23:02 evertbook5 systemd[2738]: tracker-miner-fs.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 45.
```

There's isntructions to permanently stop this process, but I would rather to see it work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Removing the tracker database seems to have done the trick:

```
rm -r ~/.cache/tracker
```

Comment: what is tracker miner? was consuming 100% of my cpu usage 10' ago

Answer (score 5):

This solution worked for me...

So how to completely disable Tracker, so it no longer indexes any files, and stop having any Tracker process running in the background? You can mask the Tracker systemd services to completely disable it for your current user using this command:

```
$ systemctl --user mask tracker-store.service tracker-miner-fs.service tracker-miner-rss.service tracker-extract.service tracker-miner-apps.service tracker-writeback.service
```

After this, reset Tracker:

```
$ tracker reset --hard
```

And reboot.

Source: https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/07/how-to-completely-disable-tracker.html

Answer (score 1):

For me the key was that tracker was running for system accounts with no home directory (pihole in my case). Once I created a home dir for pihole, problem was resolved (fingers crossed). I looked up the process id from syslog in 'ps -ef' to see which user tracker was running for

Answer (score 0):

`tracker-miner` is having problems with files in your `/home/evert/Music/unsorted/iTunes Music` folder. Did your system need an fsck?

Tracker's metadata miners can crash on certain file contents. If you find you have a core stuck at 100%, take a look in `/tmp/tracker-extract-files.1000` and you'll likely find a symlink to a problem file. Stop the tracker daemon, move the file (or exclude the directory) and restart the process. It should settle down after a while, as long as the miner never sees that problem file again.

More possibly appropriate details in my answer: [no progress updates from gnome tracker - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/914581/no-progress-updates-from-gnome-tracker/914602#914602)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work for everybody. But I just deleted

> ~/.cache/tracker3/files

and then restarted the laptop, checked System Monitor, tracker3-extract took sometime and wrote about 2GB disk. It's been few days now and I don't see tracker-miner-fs-3 rising.
You can access .cache by enabling show hidden files.