# tracker-miner-f taking over 100% of cpu

Tags: 20.04, tracker

I am working with Ubuntu 20.04 and currently, I have a tracker-miner-f eating up my cpu.
[image]

What is this? Why is the cpu usage over 100%? Is it problematic?

Kind regards

Comment: If it lasts a long time (i.e. isn't just some transient processing), try moving all the files in your Desktop folder to another folder, and then rebooting. (there's a bug in the desktop icons extension that can cause problems in certain situations)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tracker process taking lot of CPU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187191/tracker-process-taking-lot-of-cpu)

Answer (score 3):

I was facing tracker processes spiking with a high CPU usage followed exits with failure exit code, especially `tracker-miner-fs-3`. I followed [this suggestion from @evert](https://askubuntu.com/a/1232687/1616803)  and removed tracker cache. That was enough for my case.

```
rm -r ~/.cache/tracker
```

Maybe for my case running `tracker3 reset -s` (to reset the filesystem cache) could be enough, but, yeah, cleaning the whole cache worked.