# Gnome gconf-editor crippled in 18.04

Tags: command-line, gnome, 18.04

I want to modify preferences for gnome-terminal and gnome-editor from the command line. To do this I need to know the various relevant key-value pairs and gconf-editor used to display them for all Gnome-based apps. Unfortunately, in 18.04 desktop gconf.editor only shows values for gconf-editor itself and not for any other Gnome applications.

Given this, what is the best way to change Gnome app preferences from the command line in 18.04?

Comment: Use `dconf`, `dconf-editor` (instead of `gconf-editor`) and `gsettings`

Comment: There's a nice answer here as well: https://askubuntu.com/a/191013/248158