# Alt key caught by ubuntu, can't use intellij keybindings (and want to key the bindings I know)

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 18.10

I wonder if you can help. I recently upgraded to 18.10 and with that I can't use the keybindings I am used to. 
I fixed some other issues with `dconf-editor` and the `Keyboard` menu on settings but I can't find what catches `Alt`, I would appreciate any guidance to learn how to change ubuntu (I want to keep using the keybindings I used in intellij for years)

EDIT 0 : I used 16.04 with unity before and the keybindings where ok.

EDIT 1: Some examples of keybindings that I use a lot: Alt + Space, Alt+Shift+F7, Alt+= there are quite a few that are `Alt` based.

EDIT 2: I guess the ideal solution would be to have a way to list the key shortcuts ubuntu uses and then I can write a script to ensure the key bindings I need are left free... alternatively perhpas there is a way to tell ubuntu to not catch most keys when intellij is running

Comment: Is an earlier version of Ubuntu working like you want it to work? In that case, which version?

Comment: You can try Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS live without installing, and you can try other flavours of Ubuntu live (Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Ubuntu Budgie, ... Xubuntu, which have different desktop environments). You might find one of these better, and in that case, you can install it. -- Of course you can also go back to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, which is supported until April 2021.

Comment: It is a nice suggestion @sudodus I would like to try to learn how this works, tho.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have managed to do most of what I want with some help from this (answer) [[What is dconf, what is its function, and how do I use it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22313/what-is-dconf-what-is-its-function-and-how-do-i-use-it]) 
the TL;DR is use

`gsettings list-recursively | egrep "*Alt*"`

to find the where the keybindings are used and then the `dconf-editor` to change those settings. 
If there is a more systematic way to do this, that would be great.