# How to make in CLI check for updates to be happening every 4 weeks and install them automatically without going to Software sources?

Tags: command-line, updates

I have a set of [custom commands](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kangarooo) I run on my computers after I install them. How do I make Ubuntu check for updates every 4 weeks and install them automatically on check?

I would need this done via command line so I can set it up for usual users when I set up their computers.

The first command will make the update manager check for updates every 2 weeks because they not always come so much and to save the bandwidth of the Ubuntu servers.

I also need to set it so that users don't need to click to install updates since it's tiring every time I help a friend set up a computer.

Answer (score 10):

First, enable automatic updates like this:

```
sudo apt-get install unattended-upgrades
```

You then need to edit its configuration, type

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades
```

(replace `nano` with your preferred text editor if you want)

The file looks like this:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
        "Ubuntu maverick-security";
//      "Ubuntu maverick-updates";
};
```

The `//` means this line is a *comment* and won't be considered by the program, remove the strokes to include stable release updates in addition to security fixes. Also, replace `maverick` with the version of Ubuntu you're running.

To set the interval at which the system checks for updates, edit the `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic` file with a text editor:

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "14";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "14";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "14";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "14";
```

In this example, the system is updated every two weeks.

For a more detailed explanation, see [Automatic Updates](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.10/serverguide/C/automatic-updates.html) in the Ubuntu server guide.

---

Note that papukaija's answer is talking about the interval at which the Update Manager dialogue pops up on your screen, I'm guessing that's not what you wan't, but I'm not sure. :)

Comment: Dialogs not needed to pop up and it not going in 1 line. If i set in Software sources 2 weeks to be checked then is it possible that update dialog pops up earlier or later? Needed is that with 1 line would be possible to set up that user wouldnt even know he has system beeing updated every 4 weeks and he doesnt needs to see any updates asking and automatically its just installed. So i dont need to set that manually with mouse in Software sources.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. You can disable the update notifications by going to System → Preferences → Startup Applications and removing the check mark at "Update Notifier". Is that what you meant? Also, of course you can set it to "30" instead of "14" days (or any amount you want)

Comment: And that can be also done with one line? If yes thats also good to do if not- its not main thing i wanted. Main thing is to overcome going to Software sources setings to change update checking and what to do. I want to put check every 28 days and install updates without asking anything in terminal so its faster.

Comment: One line command in my answer: apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y

Comment: @luri that's not what this question is about

Comment: Sorry then... I'm starting to think I'll understand the question when I see the right answer... and not before

Answer (score 2):

If you mean update everything "updatable", i.e., update ALL your packages, I guess you could cron (within the root cron) than every 28 days `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y` is run.

Some people have problems with crond jobs because of a restrictive `PATH` setting. Should you have any problem you can define your `PATH` at the very beginning of the `crontab -e` file (as suggested in [CronHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto))

Also, to check that everything is going OK, I'd log the results, like this:

```
root@PORTATIL:/var/log$ crontab -l
* * */2 * * /usr/share/myupdate.sh > /var/log/myupdate.log
```

`myupdate.sh` could be as simple as this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Testing updates
echo "$(date) Crond myupdate sarting."
apt-get update -y
apt-get upgrade -y
echo "$(date)Crond myupdate finished."
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. When I get my cron logs, `aptitude -y safe-upgrade` is complaining about needing a controlling tty, and then a bunch of path errors. Maybe I should make a question..

Comment: Did you set it within the root cron?

Comment: Yep. It was failing because of some different path problems, so I made a script at /root/bin, with #!/bin/bash, and full path to apt-get. It works better, but it still doesn't upgrade.

Comment: Post the errors in the log.... or whatever fails

Comment: I made a separate question: http://askubuntu.com/q/23795/8515

Comment: I guess the important thing to include in this answer is a warning about path problems when using cron. Declaring the path in the cron file (or in a script cron runs) is necessary.

Comment: I added my comment there, but will do here also.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the interval between the time when update-manager is run by opening [gconf-editor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17249/how-do-i-use-the-gconf-editor) (for example with Alt+F2 and typing gconf-editor). Then locate `/apps/update-notifier`.

The interval is defined in key `regular_auto_launch_interval` where the value is number of days. I think that this method doesn't affect the non-graphical automatic updater (unattended-upgrades).

Please note that Ubuntu may not automatically install security updates due to a [bug](http://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/549217).

Comment: This is the command line version of this answer: `gconftool -s /apps/update-notifier/regular_auto_launch_interval --type int 7` (where 7 is the interval in days)

Comment: I just checked it was already 7. But in Software sources its set 2 weeks. Maybe its somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

I put `gconftool -s /apps/update-notifier/regular_auto_launch_interval --type int 1` and its opening every day showing i have not installed updates. Does it open if theres no new updates? So then making auto update every 4 weeks would not make this pop up? So then just how to make with CLI to auto install updates every checking every 4 weeks? THats what i want. By not going to Software sources and doing it with mouse. And doing so its possible couse it cant be put more then 2 weeks in there.