# How do I get Wingpanel to replace the default Gnome Panel?

Tags: gnome-panel, wingpanel

I've installed wingpanel, but as I launch it, the regular Gnome Panel won't disappear. I also tried `wingpanel --replace` but it doesn't change the situation. However, when executing `killall gnome-panel`, for those few seconds of a panel free desktop, the Wingpanel appears on the top right corner, just to disappear as Gnome Panel is restored. Any advice on how to make this work is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To completly disable Gnome Panel run `gconf-editor` and navigate through **Desktop → Gnome → Session → Required Components** and double click on `panel` and remove value `gnome-panel` (make the field blank).

- [How do I use the gconf editor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17249/how-do-i-use-the-gconf-editor)

Comment: Or replace it with wingpanel. This section is there to make sure whatever panel solution you want is always running. Take advantage of it.